# Using Texmaker with glossaries on Windows

Tags: glossaries, texmaker

Is there a simple way of integrating `glossaries` package with [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) on Windows?

I was following a very nice [tutorial](http://www.latex-community.org/know-how/263-glossaries-nomenclature-lists-of-symbols-and-acronyms) to understand how `glossaries` package works, but got stuck when trying to make it actually generate an index as I don't know where and how to add the `makeglossaries` command in TexMaker to make it run together with pdflatex.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `makeglossaries` program is quite easy to use: if your main LaTeX file is called `file.tex`, then all that's needed is to run

```
makeglossaries file
```

To add a suitable action in Texmaker, just go to the

> User > User commands > Edit User Commands

menu entry and, in the window that appears, add

```
makeglossaries
```

in the upper box (it's just the name which will be shown in the "User>User Commands" drop down menu) and

```
makeglossaries %
```

in the lower box. Then, in order to run `makeglossaries` on the current file, just choose the new menu item (or use the keyboard shortcut shown next to the menu entry). The `%` stands for the current file name (without extension), as explained in the window.

It's probably possible to define an action that concatenates executions of `pdflatex`, `makeglossaries` and `pdflatex` again, but I think it's not necessary to have glossaries synchronized at *each* compilation during document preparation. Just be confident that they will be when `makeglossaries` is run and `pdflatex` is run again.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! BTW, is there a way to make TexMaker run all bibtex, makeglossaries and pdflatex with just one command this way?

Comment: @mmm As I said, there's rarely the need that glossaries, index and bibliography are *always* synchronized. We *are* sure that they will be at the end. Running each time all auxiliary programs is usually a waste of time.

Comment: You may be right in most cases, but as I'm working to structure my thesis and work very intensively to get my indexes right, it's really rather a time saver in my case. So I added an user action:
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex | makeglossaries % | pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
which does what I wanted.

Comment: you saved my life!

Comment: After (User > User commands > Edit User Commands) and entering in the variations of makeindex without and with the % in the upper and lower boxes respectively one should be able to just be able to select that command 'makeglossaries' (which appears as a shortcut in the same dropdown in which one can choose 'QuickBuild', 'PDFLatex' etc.), after running the makeglossaries one should get a glossary? I have tried running it several times, cleaning etc. then running Quickbuild as well as ViewPDF, on the example first found here: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Glossaries  is glossaryless..

Comment: How do I do this when using a build folder? If I use `makeglossaries %` I get `Auxiliary file 'filename.aux' doesn't exist. Have you run LaTeX?` and if I use `makeglossaries ./build/%` I get `Auxiliary file '.aux' doesn't exist. Have you run LaTeX?`

Answer (score 8):

To complement egreg's answer. A very simple way to integrate glossaries in Texmaker (windows) is to add `automake` in the `usepackage{glossaries}` option like this

```
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries}
```

This automatically makes the glossaries.

Credits to [Niclola Talbot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110095/list-of-acronyms-is-not-displayed/112487#112487).
Nic pointed out that this feature was "(Introduced in glossaries version 4.08.) This will try to get TeX to run the external applications ...."

For more, see [Nic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110095/list-of-acronyms-is-not-displayed/112487#112487)

Comment: This helped big time for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try have a look here:

There is wiki entrance here.

http://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=LaTeX/Glossary&stable=0#Compile_glossary_-_In_windows_with_texmaker

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)