# How to sort alphabet index in Vietnamese correctly?

Tags: indexing, languages, sorting

I want to use `index` in Vietnamese Alphabetically. The order must be a, b, c, d, đ, e, ê. But in following code. That order is wrong. The first is "Ê", not "A", the second is "Đ", not "B". How to arrange that order?[image]

This is my code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=3]
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello}

Some text.\index{Apple}\index{Apricot}\index{Avocado}\index{Banana}
\index{Bilberry}\index{Blackberry}\index{Blackcurrant}\index{Blueberry}
\index{Currant}\index{Cherry}\index{Cherimoya}\index{Clementine}
\index{Date}\index{Damson}\index{Dragonfruit}\index{Durian}
\index{Eggplant}\index{Elderberry}\index{Feijoa}\index{Gooseberry}
\index{Grape}\index{Grapefruit}\index{Guava}\index{Huckleberry}
\index{Jackfruit}\index{Jambul}\index{Kiwi fruit}\index{Kumquat}
\index{Legume}\index{Lemon}\index{Lime}\index{Lychee}\index{Mandarine}
\index{Mango}\index{Melon}\index{Nectarine}\index{Orange}\index{Peach}
\index{Pear}\index{Pitaya}\index{Physalis}\index{Plum}\index{Pineapple}
\index{Pomegranate}\index{Purple Mangosteen}\index{Raisin}\index{Raspberry}
\index{Rambutan}\index{Redcurrant}\index{Salal berry}\index{Satsuma}
\index{Star fruit}\index{Strawberry}\index{Tangerine}\index{Tomato}
\index{Ugli fruit}\index{Watermelon}\index{Ziziphus mauritiana}
\index{Đồng biến}
\index{Nghịch biến}
\index{Dao động điều hòa}
\index{Ếch}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm afraid MakeIndex is unable to sort taking into account complex rules (it's basically ASCII). Possibly Xindy is the way to go, but I don't know if it supports Vietnamese, yet.

Comment: For cross reference: [Sorting Vietnamese utf8 index with make-rules in xindy package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142345).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As Egreg said, makeindex, which is used with `imakeidx` to produce index by default, doesn't support unicode. There is support for vietnamese in `xindy`, the other index processor. Unfortunately, there is some problem with pdflatex, Vietnamese language and xindy, because index entries are written as TeX sequences, not utf-8 codes, and xindy is unable to sort them correctly. This doesn't happen with other languages, so it is probably a bug. Nevertheless, you can switch to `xelatex`, which is good idea for Asian language anyway, and the index is then processed correctly, I hope.

Modified preamble:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{vietnamese}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=3,options={-M lang/vietnamese/utf8-lang}]
```

For xelatex, use `polyglossia` package instead of `vietnam`, we use `xindy` option for `imakeidx` to avoid `makeindex` usage and `options={-M lang/vietnamese/utf8-lang}` will use Vietnamese sorting.

compile with `xelatex -shell-escape filename`. the `-shell-escape` option enables compilation of the index directly when your document is compiled. if you are not using the command line to compile your document, you must configure your editor to use this option.

The result:

[image: Vietnamese index]

**Edit:**
As workaround for pdflatex, I wrote simple filter which convert control sequences generated by `inputenc` with `utf8` option to `utf8` characters.

iec2utf.lua:

```lua
kpse.set_program_name("luatex")

local cmd_arg = [[
iec2utf.lua - Script for converting LaTeX LICR codes to utf8 characters
Usage: cat filename | texlua iec2utf.lua > newfilename

Parameters:
  comma separated list of LaTeX font encodings used in the document
]]

local enc = {}

local licrs = {}
local codepoint2utf = unicode.utf8.char 

function load_encodings(f)
  local file= io.open(f,"r")
  local encodings = file:read("*all")
  file:close()
  for codepoint, licr in encodings:gmatch('DeclareUnicodeCharacter(%b{})(%b{})') do
    local codepoint = codepoint2utf(tonumber(codepoint:sub(2,-2),16))
    local licr= licr:sub(2,-2):gsub('@tabacckludge','')
    licrs[licr] = codepoint
  end
end

function sanitize_licr(l)
  return l:gsub(" (.)",function(s) if s:match("[%a]") then return " "..s else return s end end):sub(2,-2)
end
if arg[1] == nil then
  enc = {"T1"}
else
  for _,n in pairs(arg) do
    enc[#enc+1] = n
  end
end

for _,e in pairs(enc) do
  local filename = e:lower() .. "enc.dfu"
  local dfufile = kpse.find_file(filename)
  if dfufile then
    load_encodings(dfufile)
  end
end

local input = io.read("*all")

local cache = {}

local output = input:gsub('\\IeC[%s]*(%b{})',function(iec)
  local code = cache[iec] or licrs[sanitize_licr(iec)] or '\\IeC '..iec
  -- print(iec, code)
  cache[iec] = code
  return code
end)

io.write(output)
```

save this script to the same directory as your tex file. This script takes as parameter used font encoding, which is T5 in the case of Vietnamese.

if you are using Windows, you can create batch script to use this filter:

vietxindy.bat:

```
@echo of
type %~n1.idx | texlua iec2utf.lua T5 | texindy -i -M lang/vietnamese/utf8-lang -o %~n1.ind
```

for Linux, create shell script `vietxindy`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
texlua iec2utf.lua T5 < `basename $1 .tex`.idx | texindy -i -M lang/vietnamese/utf8-lang -o `basename $1 .tex`.ind
```

And then compile the document with:

```
pdflatex filename 
vietxindy filename
pdflatex filename
```

from the command line

Comment: I can not compile with xelatex -shell-escape filename. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: @minthao_2011 doest it fail with some error message?

Comment: No. I don't know how to  compile with xelatex -shell-escape filename.

Comment: @minthao_2011 do you compile from the command line, or directly from your text editor?

Comment: I get the warning Package expl3 Error: Mismatched LaTeX3 packages detected

Comment: @minthao_2011 do you use recent tex distribution? maybe try to upgrade, maybe either polyglossia or imakeidx on your computer are too old

Answer (score 8):

Here's another possible solution that uses [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) instead:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

\usepackage[xindy={codepage=utf8,language=vietnamese},nopostdot]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

\glossarystyle{mcolindex}
\renewcommand{\glsmcols}{3}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\glsindex}[1]{%
  \def\theglslabel{#1}%
  \def\theglsname{#1}%
  \@onelevel@sanitize\theglslabel
  \ifglsentryexists{\theglslabel}%
  {%
  }%
  {%
    \newglossaryentry{\theglslabel}%
      {name={#1},text={\expandonce\theglsname},description={}}%
  }%
  \glsadd{\theglslabel}%
}
\makeatother

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello}

Some text.\glsindex{Apple}\glsindex{Apricot}\glsindex{Avocado}\glsindex{Banana}
\glsindex{Bilberry}\glsindex{Blackberry}\glsindex{Blackcurrant}\glsindex{Blueberry}
\glsindex{Currant}\glsindex{Cherry}\glsindex{Cherimoya}\glsindex{Clementine}
\glsindex{Date}\glsindex{Damson}\glsindex{Dragonfruit}\glsindex{Durian}
\glsindex{Eggplant}\glsindex{Elderberry}\glsindex{Feijoa}\glsindex{Gooseberry}
\glsindex{Grape}\glsindex{Grapefruit}\glsindex{Guava}\glsindex{Huckleberry}
\glsindex{Jackfruit}\glsindex{Jambul}\glsindex{Kiwi fruit}\glsindex{Kumquat}
\glsindex{Legume}\glsindex{Lemon}\glsindex{Lime}\glsindex{Lychee}\glsindex{Mandarine}
\glsindex{Mango}\glsindex{Melon}\glsindex{Nectarine}\glsindex{Orange}\glsindex{Peach}
\glsindex{Pear}\glsindex{Pitaya}\glsindex{Physalis}\glsindex{Plum}\glsindex{Pineapple}
\glsindex{Pomegranate}\glsindex{Purple Mangosteen}\glsindex{Raisin}\glsindex{Raspberry}
\glsindex{Rambutan}\glsindex{Redcurrant}\glsindex{Salal berry}\glsindex{Satsuma}
\glsindex{Star fruit}\glsindex{Strawberry}\glsindex{Tangerine}\glsindex{Tomato}
\glsindex{Ugli fruit}\glsindex{Watermelon}\glsindex{Ziziphus mauritiana}
\glsindex{Đồng biến}
\glsindex{Nghịch biến}
\glsindex{Dao động điều hòa}
\glsindex{Ếch}

\printglossary[title=\indexname]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Image of index]

Requires (pdf)latex, makeglossaries, (pdf)latex

**Edit:**

Further information on using the `glossaries` package:

- [Guide for Beginners (PDF)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf)
- [Main User Manual (PDF)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf)
- [Glossaries, Nomenclature, Lists of Symbols and Acronyms](http://www.latex-community.org/know-how/latex/55-latex-general/263-glossaries-nomenclature-lists-of-symbols-and-acronyms)
- [Creating Glossaries, Lists of Symbols or Acronyms (glossaries package)](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/html/makeglossaries.html)

Comment: I can not view the output. I only see the first page.

Comment: @minthao_2011 Did you run `makeglossaries` after running `latex` (or `pdflatex`)? See [Glossaries, Nomenclature, Lists of Symbols and Acronyms](http://www.latex-community.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=263:glossaries-nomenclature-lists-of-symbols-and-acronyms&catid=55:latex-general&Itemid=114#sort)

Comment: I don't know input makeglossaries. I use Texmaker.

Comment: @minthao_2011 Have a look at [Using Texmaker with glossaries on windows](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61099/using-texmaker-with-glossaries-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

This is my way, for example, if I want to sort ếch, I typed `\index{eesch@ếch}`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=2]
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello}
\index{Uwsnd dujng@Ứng dụng}
\index{ddoofng bieesn@đồng biến}
\index{nghijch bieesn@nghịch biến}
\index{Dao ddoojng ddieefu hoaf@Dao động điều hòa}
\index{eesch@ếch}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]