# How to move from makeindex to xindy?

Tags: texlive, indexing, glossaries, xindy

Is there an easy, lightweight way to manage multiple glossaries and indices using xindy rather than makeindex? Everything *works* currently using makeindex, but it's not as nice as it could be. I'm fine with how things look for now, but I'd like to start using the preferred tool as soon as possible. Evidently xindy is the way to go.

I understand a possible workaround is to use makeindex4, which is a wrapper to xindy that tries to behave like makeindex, but I'd like to avoid using yet another program, and makeindex4 doesn't come with TexLIVE 2012.

If anyone could point me to a xindy style file that is similar to the glossaries style 'altlist', I could probably modify it from there.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

(Other info: I use TexShop 2.47 for Mac.)
(Also, I LOVE this site and have found many forums very helpful. Unfortunately, I can't vote anything up because I lack reputation. I wish voting for answers would help build reputation!)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is not clear to me what kind of issues you are experiencing, so I will give you complete example on how to use modern `LaTeX` engine (`lualatex` or `xelatex`) with `xindy`. With `pdflatex`, there might be some problems with accented characters, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131356/2891) for some details.

So in our example, we have utf8 file with some Czech language index and glossary entries:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{fontspec}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[xindy={language=czech, codepage=utf8}, style=altlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage[xindy, splitindex]{imakeidx}
\usepackage[itemlayout=singlepar]{idxlayout}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\makeglossaries
\def\xindylangopt{-M lang/czech/utf8-lang}
\makeindex[options=\xindylangopt]
\makeindex[name=nameindex,title = Index of names,  options=\xindylangopt]
\newglossaryentry{first}{name = ddd, description = {První položka}}
\newglossaryentry{second}{name = čokoláda, description = {Druhá položka}}
\newglossaryentry{third}{name = cosi, description = {Třetí položka}}
\begin{document}
  Hello worls, \gls{first}, \gls{second} and \gls{third}
  \index[nameindex]{Čapek, Karel}
  \index[nameindex]{Hašek, Jaroslav}
  \index[nameindex]{Cílek, Václav}
  \index[nameindex]{Deml, Jakub}
  \index[nameindex]{Chalupa, Václav}
  \index{Hello|see{Entry}}
  \index{Entry!Subentry}
  \index{Entry!Another subentry}
  \index{What|textbf}
  \printglossary
  \printindex[nameindex]
  \printindex
\end{document}
```

Some important points:

```
\usepackage[xindy={language=czech, codepage=utf8}, style=altlist]{glossaries}
```

`glossaries` package have built in xindy support, we only have to set xindy option and pass correct arguments for language and codepage.  `makeglossaries` script will take care of correct xindy call for us.

```
\usepackage[xindy, splitindex]{imakeidx}
...
\def\xindylangopt{-M lang/czech/utf8-lang}
\makeindex[options=\xindylangopt]
\makeindex[name=nameindex,title = Index of names,  options=\xindylangopt]
```

for index creation, we use `imakeidx` package. There we create two indexes, one general and other for names. `xindy` option will call xindy automatically on `LaTeX` run

`\xindylangopt` macro defines xindy options for language processing, `-M lang/czech/utf8-lang` will use xindy module for the Czech language in `utf8` encoding.

two uses of `\makeindex` will create two indexes, there are many options which can be used for formatting of these indexes, see `imakeidx` manual.

For example of another mean of controlling index appearance, I used also

```
\usepackage[itemlayout=singlepar]{idxlayout}
```

which will result in index in run-in style. I don't like it much, I just wanted to show you what can be done :). `idxlayout` package really isn't necessary, but maybe you will find it useful.

Now how to compile the example:

```
lualatex sample.tex
makeglossaries sample
lualatex -shell-escape sample.tex
```

first `lualatex` run will write glossary and index entries, `makeglossaries` script will compile the glossary, second `lualatex` run is with `-shell-escape` option, so indexes are creaed by `imakeidx` automatically.

The result:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm working through this in applying it to my problem. It looks good -- thanks! I'm having a little trouble getting stuff to compile perfectly on my bigger example. Should this work using LaTeX rather than LuaTeX?

Comment: this should work for lualatex or xelatex, for pdflatex, you will need to preprocess the `.idx` file with script provided in this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131334/how-to-sort-alphabet-index-in-vietnamese-correctly/131356#131356

Comment: It works great with makeindex, but with xindy it gives 
'    Processing index...
    ERROR: CHAR: index 0 should be less than the length of the string'
Does that look familiar?

Comment: Aha! That error was because xindy needed a sort-key defined for any glossary entry whose name was itself a macro. When I gave those glossary entries a sort key, it compiled and worked great with lualatex, bibtex and makeglossaries. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: what if you want to use two languages simultaneously?

Comment: Your answer mentions the language module lang/czech/utf8-lang; what other modules are available? In particular, if my principle language is English.

Comment: How to get the subentries of `Entry`: `\index{Entry!Subentry}` and
`\index{Entry!Another subentry}` ?

Comment: @tatojo subentries should be supported, but in my example they are printed on one line, because of `singlepar` option for `idxlayout` package. Just don't use this option.