# Sorting Vietnamese utf8 index with make-rules in xindy package

Tags: indexing, glossaries, accents, sorting, xindy

I am using the `xindy` package to compile the index containing Vietnamese. It
works fine except the order within words. The "standard" order is accepted
as the following, which is different from the current `xindy` default order:

> a à ả ã á ạ ă ằ ẳ ẵ ắ ặ â ầ ẩ ẫ ấ ậ b c d đ e è ẻ ẽ é ẹ ê ề ể ễ ế ệ f g h i
>   ì ỉ ĩ í ị j k l m n o ò ỏ õ ó ọ ô ồ ổ ỗ ố ộ ơ ờ ở ỡ ớ ợ p q r s t u ù ủ ũ ú
>   ụ ư ừ ử ữ ứ ự v w x y ỳ ỷ ỹ ý ỵ z

I edited the *vietnamese/utf8.pl.in* (attached below) and tested with
this version. However, there are some words that are ordered in an unexpected way.
The expected order, for example, should be,

1. Hiên
2. Hiền
3. Hiển
4. Hiễn
5. Hiến
6. Hiện

But it is not sorted in that order, i.e., the two last numbers, 5 & 6, are
now placed at the positions of 3 & 4. The same happened with words: Lan Làn
Lản Lãn Lán Lạn (note the tonal diacritics).

The question here is: **Why are the *Lán, Lạn* sorted before *Lản, Lãn*, given that the rules provided in the script?**

Anyone?

Here is the revised make-rules perl script for Vietnamese:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$language = "Vietnamese";
$prefix = "vi";
$script = "latin";

$alphabet = [
['A',  ['a','A'],['à','À'],['ả','Ả'],['ã','Ã'],['á','Á'],['ạ','Ạ']],
['Ă',  ['ă','Ă'],['ằ','Ằ'],['ẳ','Ẳ'],['ẵ','Ẵ'],['ắ','Ắ'],['ặ','Ặ']],
['Â',  ['â','Â'],['ầ','Ầ'],['ẩ','Ẩ'],['ẫ','Ẫ'],['ấ','Ấ'],['ậ','Ậ']],
               [], # a with ogonek (polish)
['B',  ['b','B']],
               [], # b with hook (hausa)
['C',  ['c','C']],
               [], # ch (spanish/traditonal)
               [], # cs (hungarian)
               [], # c with caron (many)
               [], # c with acute (croatian, lower sorbian, polish)
               [], # c with circumflex (esperanto)
               [], # c with cedilla (albanian, kurdish, turkish)
['D',  ['d','D']],
               [], # dh (albanian)
               [], # dz (hungarian)
               [], # dzs (hungarian)
               [], # d+z with caron (croatian)
               [], # d+z with acute (upper sorbian)
               [], # d with caron (slovak/large)
['Đ',  ['đ','Đ']],
               [], # d with hook (hausa)
               [], # eth (icelandic)
['E',  ['e','E'],['è','È'],['ẻ','Ẻ'],['ẽ','Ẽ'],['é','É'],['ẹ','Ẹ']],
               [], # e with caron (lower/upper sorbian)
['Ê',  ['ê','Ê'],['ề','Ề'],['ể','Ể'],['ễ','Ễ'],['ế','Ế'],['ệ','Ệ']],
               [], # e with diaeresis (albanian)
               [], # e with ogonek (polish)
['F',  ['f','F']],
['G',  ['g','G']],
               [], # gj (albanian)
               [], # gy (hungarian)
               [], # g with circumflex (esperanto)
               [], # g with breve (turkish)
               [], # g with cedilla/comma (latvian)
               [], # postpalatal fricative (gypsy/northrussian)
['H',  ['h','H']],
               [], # h with circumflex (esperanto)
               [], # ch (many)
               [], # dotless i (turkish)
['I',  ['i','I'],['ì','Ì'],['ỉ','Ỉ'],['ĩ','Ĩ'],['í','Í'],['ị','Ị']],
               [], # i with inverted breve below (gypsy/northrussian)
               [], # i with circumflex (kurdish, romanian)
               [], # i with diaeresis (gypsy/northrussian)
['J',  ['j','J']],
               [], # j with circumflex (esperanto)
['K',  ['k','K']],
               [], # kh (gypsy/northrussian)
               [], # k with cedilla/comma (latvian)
               [], # k with hook (hausa)
               [], # x (gypsy/northrussian)
               [], # l with stroke (lower/upper sorbian)
['L',  ['l','L']],
               [], # lj (croatian)
               [], # ll (albanian, spanish/traditonal)
               [], # ly (hungarian)
               [], # l with cedilla/comma (latvian)
               [], # l with stroke (polish)
               [], # l with caron (slovak/large)
['M',  ['m','M']],
['N',  ['n','N']],
               [], # nj (albanian, croatian)
               [], # ny (hungarian)
               [], # n with caron (slovak/large)
               [], # n with acute (lower/upper sorbian, polish)
               [], # n with tilde (spanish/modern, spanish/traditional)
               [], # n with cedilla/comma (latvian)
['O',  ['o','O'],['ò','Ò'],['ỏ','Ỏ'],['õ','Õ'],['ó','Ó'],['ọ','Ọ']],
               [], # o with acute (polish, upper sorbian)
['Ô',  ['ô','Ô'],['ồ','Ồ'],['ổ','Ổ'],['ỗ','Ỗ'],['ố','Ố'],['ộ','Ộ']],
['Ơ',  ['ơ','Ơ'],['ờ','Ờ'],['ở','Ở'],['ỡ','Ỡ'],['ớ','Ớ'],['ợ','Ợ']],
               [], # o with diaeresis (hungarian, turkish)
['P',  ['p','P']],
               [], # ph (gypsy/northrussian)
['Q',  ['q','Q']],
['R',  ['r','R']],
               [], # rr (albanian)
               [], # r with caron (czech, slovak/large, upper sorbian)
               [], # r with acute (lower sorbian)
               [], # r with cedilla/comma (latvian)
['S',  ['s','S']],
               [], # sh (albanian)
               [], # sz (hungarian)
               [], # s with caron (many)
               [], # s with acute (lower sorbian, polish)
               [], # s with circumflex (esperanto)
               [], # s with comma below (romanian)
               [], # s with cedilla (kurdish, turkish)
               [], # z (estonian)
               [], # z with caron (estonian)
['T',  ['t','T']],
               [], # th (albanian)
               [], # ty (hungarian)
               [], # t with caron (slovak/large)
               [], # t with comma below (romanian)
               [], # c with acute (upper sorbian) @@
['U',  ['u','U'],['ù','Ù'],['ủ','Ủ'],['ũ','Ũ'],['ú','Ú'],['ụ','Ụ']],
               [], # u with breve (esperanto)
               [], # u with circumflex (kurdish)
['Ư',  ['ư','Ư'],['ừ','Ừ'],['ử','Ử'],['ữ','Ữ'],['ứ','Ứ'],['ự','Ự']],
               [], # u with diaeresis (hungarian, turkish)
['V',  ['v','V']],
['W',  ['w','W']],
               [], # o with tilde (estonian)
               [], # a with diaeresis (estonian)
               [], # o with diaeresis (estonian)
               [], # u with diaeresis (estonian)
['X',  ['x','X']],
               [], # xh (albanian)
['Y',  ['y','Y'],['ỳ','Ỳ'],['ỷ','Ỷ'],['ỹ','Ỹ'],['ý','Ý'],['ỵ','Ỵ']],
               [], # y preceded by apostrophe (hausa)
               [], # yogh (english)
['Z',  ['z','Z']],
               [], # zh (albanian)
               [], # zs (hungarian)
               [], # z with caron (many)
               [], # z with acute (lower sorbian, polish)
               [], # z with dot above (polish)
               [], # thorn (icelandic)
               [], # wynn (english)
               [], # ligature ae (danish, icelandic, norwegian)
               [], # o with stroke (danish, norwegian)
               [], # a with ring above (danish, norwegian, swedish)
               [], # a with diaeresis (finnish, swedish)
               [], # o with diaeresis (finnish, swedish)
               [], # a with ring above (icelandic)
];

$sortcase = 'Aa';
#$sortcase = 'aA';

$ligatures = [
];

@special = ('?', '!', '.', 'letters', '-', '\'');

do 'make-rules.pl';
```

Comment: For cross reference: [How to sort alphabet index in Vietnamese correctly?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131334).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Longer post

I can confirm that, for instance we can compare http://vietunicode.sourceforge.net/charset/quytacABC_en.html written by a native Vietnamese and a listing of alphabets from xindy, http://xindy.sourceforge.net/doc/make-rules-alphabets-doc.pdf, page 41, there are differences as stated in the question.

I believe that the reason for this error is that the Western European languages (`general` style in `xindy`) don't recognize all the tonal diacritics. Those we know are sorted and those two unrecognized marks were put at the end of a sorting order. These things happen.

How to fix it? Just editing `vietnamese/utf8.pl.in` is not enough, it is a Perl script to generate the necessary files, especially the `xdy` files. I strongly don't recommend to edit this file directly as it is an official version and can be automatically overwritten with a new version of `xindy` when TeXLive/MikTeX is updated.

This is what I did to fix it locally in my working directory:

- I downloaded the latest version of `xindy-make-rules` from http://sourceforge.net/projects/xindy/files/xindy-make-rules/0.2/ to my working directory.
- I unzipped the file.
- I made a backup by copying `alphabets/vietnamese` directory to a new folder named `alphabets/vietnamesemal`. I entered that new folder.
- There is just one file. I made a copy of it and named it `utf8.pl-mal.in` to keep the original version in the same folder, if needed later.
- I edited this file in `gEdit`, http://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit. It is one of many editors capable of handling full set of UTF-8 characters.
- I rearranged the characters according to the Vietnamese sorting rules. This is the new file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$language = "Vietnamese";
$prefix = "vi";
$script = "latin";

$alphabet = [
['A',  ['a','A'],['à','À'],['ả','Ả'],['ã','Ã'],['á','Á'],['ạ','Ạ']],
['Ă',  ['ă','Ă'],['ằ','Ằ'],['ẳ','Ẳ'],['ẵ','Ẵ'],['ắ','Ắ'],['ặ','Ặ']],
['Â',  ['â','Â'],['ầ','Ầ'],['ẩ','Ẩ'],['ẫ','Ẫ'],['ấ','Ấ'],['ậ','Ậ']],
                   [], # a with ogonek (polish)
['B',  ['b','B']],
                   [], # b with hook (hausa)
['C',  ['c','C']],
                   [], # ch (spanish/traditonal)
                   [], # cs (hungarian)
                   [], # c with caron (many)
                   [], # c with acute (croatian, lower sorbian, polish)
                   [], # c with circumflex (esperanto)
                   [], # c with cedilla (albanian, kurdish, turkish)
['D',  ['d','D']],
                   [], # dh (albanian)
                   [], # dz (hungarian)
                   [], # dzs (hungarian)
                   [], # d+z with caron (croatian)
                   [], # d+z with acute (upper sorbian)
                   [], # d with caron (slovak/large)
['Đ',  ['đ','Đ']],
                   [], # d with hook (hausa)
                   [], # eth (icelandic)
['E',  ['e','E'],['è','È'],['ẻ','Ẻ'],['ẽ','Ẽ'],['é','É'],['ẹ','Ẹ']],
                   [], # e with caron (lower/upper sorbian)
['Ê',  ['ê','Ê'],['ề','Ề'],['ể','Ể'],['ễ','Ễ'],['ế','Ế'],['ệ','Ệ']],
                   [], # e with diaeresis (albanian)
                   [], # e with ogonek (polish)
['F',  ['f','F']],
['G',  ['g','G']],
                   [], # gj (albanian)
                   [], # gy (hungarian)
                   [], # g with circumflex (esperanto)
                   [], # g with breve (turkish)
                   [], # g with cedilla/comma (latvian)
                   [], # postpalatal fricative (gypsy/northrussian)
['H',  ['h','H']],
                   [], # h with circumflex (esperanto)
                   [], # ch (many)
                   [], # dotless i (turkish)
['I',  ['i','I'],['ì','Ì'],['ỉ','Ỉ'],['ĩ','Ĩ'],['í','Í'],['ị','Ị']],
                   [], # i with inverted breve below (gypsy/northrussian)
                   [], # i with circumflex (kurdish, romanian)
                   [], # i with diaeresis (gypsy/northrussian)
['J',  ['j','J']],
                   [], # j with circumflex (esperanto)
['K',  ['k','K']],
                   [], # kh (gypsy/northrussian)
                   [], # k with cedilla/comma (latvian)
                   [], # k with hook (hausa)
                   [], # x (gypsy/northrussian)
                   [], # l with stroke (lower/upper sorbian)
['L',  ['l','L']],
                   [], # lj (croatian)
                   [], # ll (albanian, spanish/traditonal)
                   [], # ly (hungarian)
                   [], # l with cedilla/comma (latvian)
                   [], # l with stroke (polish)
                   [], # l with caron (slovak/large)
['M',  ['m','M']],
['N',  ['n','N']],
                   [], # nj (albanian, croatian)
                   [], # ny (hungarian)
                   [], # n with caron (slovak/large)
                   [], # n with acute (lower/upper sorbian, polish)
                   [], # n with tilde (spanish/modern, spanish/traditional)
                   [], # n with cedilla/comma (latvian)
['O',  ['o','O'],['ò','Ò'],['ỏ','Ỏ'],['õ','Õ'],['ó','Ó'],['ọ','Ọ']],
                   [], # o with acute (polish, upper sorbian)
['Ô',  ['ô','Ô'],['ồ','Ồ'],['ổ','Ổ'],['ỗ','Ỗ'],['ố','Ố'],['ộ','Ộ']],
['Ơ',  ['ơ','Ơ'],['ờ','Ờ'],['ở','Ở'],['ỡ','Ỡ'],['ớ','Ớ'],['ợ','Ợ']],
                   [], # o with diaeresis (hungarian, turkish)
['P',  ['p','P']],
                   [], # ph (gypsy/northrussian)
['Q',  ['q','Q']],
['R',  ['r','R']],
                   [], # rr (albanian)
                   [], # r with caron (czech, slovak/large, upper sorbian)
                   [], # r with acute (lower sorbian)
                   [], # r with cedilla/comma (latvian)
['S',  ['s','S']],
                   [], # sh (albanian)
                   [], # sz (hungarian)
                   [], # s with caron (many)
                   [], # s with acute (lower sorbian, polish)
                   [], # s with circumflex (esperanto)
                   [], # s with comma below (romanian)
                   [], # s with cedilla (kurdish, turkish)
                   [], # z (estonian)
                   [], # z with caron (estonian)
['T',  ['t','T']],
                   [], # th (albanian)
                   [], # ty (hungarian)
                   [], # t with caron (slovak/large)
                   [], # t with comma below (romanian)
                   [], # c with acute (upper sorbian) @@
['U',  ['u','U'],['ù','Ù'],['ủ','Ủ'],['ũ','Ũ'],['ú','Ú'],['ụ','Ụ']],
                   [], # u with breve (esperanto)
                   [], # u with circumflex (kurdish)
['Ư',  ['ư','Ư'],['ừ','Ừ'],['ử','Ử'],['ữ','Ữ'],['ứ','Ứ'],['ự','Ự']],
                   [], # u with diaeresis (hungarian, turkish)
['V',  ['v','V']],
['W',  ['w','W']],
                   [], # o with tilde (estonian)
                   [], # a with diaeresis (estonian)
                   [], # o with diaeresis (estonian)
                   [], # u with diaeresis (estonian)
['X',  ['x','X']],
                   [], # xh (albanian)
['Y',  ['y','Y'],['ỳ','Ỳ'],['ỷ','Ỷ'],['ỹ','Ỹ'],['ý','Ý'],['ỵ','Ỵ']],
                   [], # y preceded by apostrophe (hausa)
                   [], # yogh (english)
['Z',  ['z','Z']],
                   [], # zh (albanian)
                   [], # zs (hungarian)
                   [], # z with caron (many)
                   [], # z with acute (lower sorbian, polish)
                   [], # z with dot above (polish)
                   [], # thorn (icelandic)
                   [], # wynn (english)
                   [], # ligature ae (danish, icelandic, norwegian)
                   [], # o with stroke (danish, norwegian)
                   [], # a with ring above (danish, norwegian, swedish)
                   [], # a with diaeresis (finnish, swedish)
                   [], # o with diaeresis (finnish, swedish)
                   [], # a with ring above (icelandic)
];

$sortcase = 'Aa';
#$sortcase = 'aA';

$ligatures = [
];

@special = ('?', '!', '.', 'letters', '-', '\'');

do 'make-rules.pl';
```

- I entered `alphabets/` directory by `cd ..`
- Then I run `perl vietnamesemal/utf8.pl-mal.in vietnamesemal/vietnamesemal`. I have got a message that `Alphabet has 126 elements.` I have received several new files there.
- I entered `vietnamesemal` again. I changed the first line in `vietnamesemal-test.xdy` to `(require "vietnamesemal.xdy")`. It means we won't need subdirectories to our work later.
- I modified `vietnamesemal-doc.tex` a bit: `\subsection` -> `\section`; `\subsubsection` to `\subsection` (four times); I commented out `\idef\fdef` (twice) and `\newpage` (once). This is the modified version of that file.

```
\section{Vietnamese}

\subsection{Alphabet}
%\icod\fcod
\begin{alphabet}
a\,A & à\,À & ả\,Ả & ã\,Ã & á\,Á & ạ\,Ạ\\
ă\,Ă & ằ\,Ằ & ẳ\,Ẳ & ẵ\,Ẵ & ắ\,Ắ & ặ\,Ặ\\
â\,Â & ầ\,Ầ & ẩ\,Ẩ & ẫ\,Ẫ & ấ\,Ấ & ậ\,Ậ\\
b\,B\\
c\,C\\
d\,D\\
đ\,Đ\\
e\,E & è\,È & ẻ\,Ẻ & ẽ\,Ẽ & é\,É & ẹ\,Ẹ\\
ê\,Ê & ề\,Ề & ể\,Ể & ễ\,Ễ & ế\,Ế & ệ\,Ệ\\
f\,F\\
g\,G\\
h\,H\\
i\,I & ì\,Ì & ỉ\,Ỉ & ĩ\,Ĩ & í\,Í & ị\,Ị\\
j\,J\\
k\,K\\
l\,L\\
m\,M\\
n\,N\\
o\,O & ò\,Ò & ỏ\,Ỏ & õ\,Õ & ó\,Ó & ọ\,Ọ\\
ô\,Ô & ồ\,Ồ & ổ\,Ổ & ỗ\,Ỗ & ố\,Ố & ộ\,Ộ\\
ơ\,Ơ & ờ\,Ờ & ở\,Ở & ỡ\,Ỡ & ớ\,Ớ & ợ\,Ợ\\
p\,P\\
q\,Q\\
r\,R\\
s\,S\\
t\,T\\
u\,U & ù\,Ù & ủ\,Ủ & ũ\,Ũ & ú\,Ú & ụ\,Ụ\\
ư\,Ư & ừ\,Ừ & ử\,Ử & ữ\,Ữ & ứ\,Ứ & ự\,Ự\\
v\,V\\
w\,W\\
x\,X\\
y\,Y & ỳ\,Ỳ & ỷ\,Ỷ & ỹ\,Ỹ & ý\,Ý & ỵ\,Ỵ\\
z\,Z
\end{alphabet}
%\idef\fdef

\subsection{Ligatures}
\begin{flushleft}
None.

\end{flushleft}

\subsection{Upper-/lowercase words}
Capitalized or uppercase words are sorted \emph{before} otherwise equal lowercase words.

\subsection{Special characters}
The order of special characters and letters is:
\begin{flushleft}
?\hspace{4mm}!\hspace{4mm}.\hspace{4mm}letters\hspace{4mm}-\hspace{4mm}'
\end{flushleft}
%\newpage
```

- I went up one level and I have modified the `alphabets-doc.tex` file quite a lot to this form. I ran it through `lualatex` which uses Latin Modern typefaces (its default font family) and it assures that all the tone marks will be typeset properly. It would be easy to get `xelatex` working on that file.

I enclose the new file and a preview of it. We can check if everything is all right, it should be now after those changes.

```
%! lualatex alphabets-doc.tex

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
%\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{luatextra}
%\usepackage[TS1,LGR,T2A,T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[latin2,cp1251,cp1252]{inputenc}
%\newcommand{\idef}{\inputencoding{cp1252}}
%\newcommand{\fdef}{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont}
%\newcommand{\icod}{\inputencoding{cp1252}}
%\newcommand{\fcod}{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont}
%\newcommand{\ienc}[1]{\renewcommand{\icod}{\inputencoding{#1}}}
%\newcommand{\fenc}[1]{\renewcommand{\fcod}{\fontencoding{#1}\selectfont}}
\newenvironment{alphabet}{\begin{tabular}{*{16}{l}}%
% &
% \small (\v{}) & \small (\'{}) & \small (\`{}) & \small (\u{}) &
% \small (\^{}) & \small (\~{}) & \small (\r{}) & \small (\"{}) &
% \small (,) & \small (\c{}) & \small (k{}) & \small (\.{}) &
% \small (-) & \small (\={}) & \small (?)\\
}{\end{tabular}}
\setlength{\topskip}{0mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-15mm}
\setlength{\textheight}{260mm}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\begin{document}
\title{Alphabets}
\author{Generated by \tt make-rules.pl}
%\maketitle
\begin{center}
  {\LARGE Alphabets} --
  \texttt{\Large Generated by \tt make-rules.pl} \par\medskip
  \large \today
\end{center}
%\tableofcontents
%\newpage
%\input{alphabets-inc.tex}
\input{vietnamesemal/vietnamesemal-doc.tex}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe1]

- In the `vietnemasemal` folder I created a new TeX file named `mal-vietnamese.tex` to test it. I have used several resources to get a longer index. The links are mentioned in the TeX file.
- I have also added word groups by creating `malstyle.xdy` file. It is a part of the `mal-vietnamese.tex` file. It uses one command named `\malgroup` and we can control its style within the TeX file directly without an additional run of `xindy`.

This is the file I mentioned:

```
%! lualatex mal-vietnamese.tex

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
% Rather new tool... %  makeindex, xindy
%\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx} 
%\makeindex[columns=3, options={-M texindy -M vietnamesemal -M malstyle}]

% The sources of data...
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142345/sorting-vietnamese-utf8-index-with-make-rules-in-xindy-package
% http://vietunicode.sourceforge.net/charset/quytacABC_en.html
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131334/how-to-sort-alphabet-index-in-vietnamese-correctly
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{malstyle.xdy}
;; malstyle.xdy
(markup-letter-group :open-head "~n\malgroup{ " :close-head " }" :capitalize)
\end{filecontents*}

\def\malgroup#1{\par\medskip\textbf{\large$\sim$#1$\sim$}\par\nopagebreak}
\begingroup
\def\thispagestyle#1{}
\printindex
\endgroup

\index{Hiên}
\index{Hiền}
\index{Hiển}
\index{Hiễn}
\index{Hiến}
\index{Hiện}

\index{Lản}
\index{Lãn}
\index{Lán}
\index{Lạn}

\index{Apple}\index{Apricot}\index{Avocado}\index{Banana}
\index{Bilberry}\index{Blackberry}\index{Blackcurrant}\index{Blueberry}
\index{Currant}\index{Cherry}\index{Cherimoya}\index{Clementine}
\index{Date}\index{Damson}\index{Dragonfruit}\index{Durian}
\index{Eggplant}\index{Elderberry}\index{Feijoa}\index{Gooseberry}
\index{Grape}\index{Grapefruit}\index{Guava}\index{Huckleberry}
\index{Jackfruit}\index{Jambul}\index{Kiwi fruit}\index{Kumquat}
\index{Legume}\index{Lemon}\index{Lime}\index{Lychee}\index{Mandarine}
\index{Mango}\index{Melon}\index{Nectarine}\index{Orange}\index{Peach}
\index{Pear}\index{Pitaya}\index{Physalis}\index{Plum}\index{Pineapple}
\index{Pomegranate}\index{Purple Mangosteen}\index{Raisin}\index{Raspberry}
\index{Rambutan}\index{Redcurrant}\index{Salal berry}\index{Satsuma}
\index{Star fruit}\index{Strawberry}\index{Tangerine}\index{Tomato}
\index{Ugli fruit}\index{Watermelon}\index{Ziziphus mauritiana}
\index{Đồng biến}
\index{Nghịch biến}
\index{Dao động điều hòa}
\index{Ếch}

Plain text\ldots
\end{document}
```

I ran these three commands and we are getting an index according to the Vietnamese sorting rules. I am submitting the `utf8.pl-mal.in` file to the authors of `xindy`, maybe they will use it in some new release of `xindy`. We will see! Enjoy and good bye! `\index{tạm biệt}`

> lualatex mal-vietnamese.tex
>   xindy -M texindy -M vietnamesemal-test -M malstyle mal-vietnamese.idx
>   lualatex mal-vietnamese.tex

[image]

---

### A working example from scratch without changing things

I cannot offer you a general solution how to set up a new version globally, I rather show you how it works in my working directory, you can probably manage the rest, if needed.

I have received first response from the `xindy` community and I have got a testing file (appreciations go to Hien Pham). Let me show you what I did:

- I created a bright new folder, `hien-example` where I will be working in.
- I created a new TeX file there, `IndexVietnamese.tex`. Because I cannot use `texindy` (my Windows home directory contains diacritical letters and I cannot change it without risk) and therefore I cannot use `imakeidx` at its best: both parameters `xindy` and `texindy` run `texindy`, I wil run this example from the command line.
- Please get `vietnamesemal-test.xdy` from my server to that directory.
- Please get `vietnamesemal.xdy` from my server as well.
- Run these four lines. If you wish to have a version without the group letters, delete `-M malstyle` (twice):

> lualatex --shell-escape IndexVietnamese.tex
>   xindy -M vietnamesemal-test -M malstyle authors.idx
>   xindy -M vietnamesemal-test -M malstyle IndexVietnamese.idx
>   lualatex --shell-escape IndexVietnamese.tex

I enclose those three files (one file in the post, two files are downloadable from my server) and a preview of page 3 (Author index) and pages 5 and 6 (Topic index).

This is the `IndexVietnamese.tex` file:

```
%! lualatex --shell-escape IndexVietnamese.tex
%! xindy -M vietnamesemal-test -M malstyle authors.idx
%! xindy -M vietnamesemal-test -M malstyle IndexVietnamese.idx
%! lualatex --shell-escape IndexVietnamese.tex

\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage[noautomatic]{imakeidx} % [noautomatic]
\makeindex[title=Topic index]
% columns=3, options={-M vietnamesemal-test},
% from lang/vietnamese/utf8-lang to a testing version
\makeindex[name=authors, title=Author index]
% columns=3, options={-M vietnamesemal-test},
% from lang/vietnamese/utf8-lang to a testing version
\makeindex
\usepackage{natbib}  

% \usepackage[noautomatic]{imakeidx}
% \makeindex[columns=3,options={-M lang/vietnamese/utf8-lang}]   
%\renewcommand\indexname{Topic index}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% For purpose of the post...
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{malstyle.xdy}
;; malstyle.xdy
(markup-letter-group :open-head "~n\malgroup{ " :close-head " }" :capitalize)
\end{filecontents*}
\def\malgroup#1{\par\medskip\textbf{\large$\sim$#1$\sim$}\par\nopagebreak}

\citeindextrue  

\chapter{Hello}

And it has fancy authors. \index[authors]{Doreian, Patrick} \index[authors]{Batagelj, Vladimir} \index[authors]{Ferligoj, Anuška}
key words: network\index{network}, blockmodeling\index{blockmodeling}, and so on.  

% I am making this index shorter to fit onto two pages...
Some text.\index{Apple}\index{Apricot}\index{Avocado}%\index{Banana}
\index{Bilberry}\index{Blackberry}\index{Blackcurrant}%\index{Blueberry}
\index{Currant}\index{Cherry}\index{Cherimoya}%\index{Clementine}
\index{Date}\index{Damson}%\index{Dragonfruit}\index{Durian}
\index{Eggplant}\index{Elderberry}\index{Feijoa}%\index{Gooseberry}
\index{Grape}\index{Grapefruit}\index{Guava}\index{Huckleberry}
\index{Jackfruit}\index{Jambul}\index{Kiwi fruit}\index{Kumquat}
\index{Legume}\index{Lemon}\index{Lime}\index{Lychee}\index{Mandarine}
\index{Mango}\index{Melon}\index{Nectarine}\index{Orange}\index{Peach}
\index{Pear}\index{Pitaya}\index{Physalis}\index{Plum}\index{Pineapple}
\index{Pomegranate}\index{Purple Mangosteen}\index{Raisin}\index{Raspberry}
\index{Rambutan}\index{Redcurrant}\index{Salal berry}\index{Satsuma}
\index{Star fruit}\index{Strawberry}\index{Tangerine}\index{Tomato}
\index{Ugli fruit}\index{Watermelon}\index{Ziziphus mauritiana}
\index{Đồng biến}
\index{Ông bà}
\index{Ăn ở}
\index{Ương ngạnh}
\index{Nghịch biến}
\index{Dao động điều hòa}
\index{Ếch}
\index{Ẩm kế}
\index{Ấm áp}
\index{Ầm ĩ}
\index{Ậm ừ}
\index{Âm hưởng}
\index{Ẫm ờ}
\index{Ơn huệ}
\index{Lan}
\index{Làn}
\index{Lãn}
\index{Lạn}
\index{Lản}
\index{Lán}
\index{Ãn}\index{An}\index{Án}\index{Ạn}\index{Àn}\index{Ản}
\index{Hiện}\index{Hiển}\index{Hiến}\index{Hiên}\index{Hiễn}\index{Hiền}
\index{choảng}\index{choạng}\index{choang}\index{choáng}\index{choãng}\index{choàng}
\index{provinces!Ontario}
\index{provinces!Saskatchewan}
\index{provinces!British Columbia}
\index{provinces!Alberta!Edmonton}
\index{territories@\textbf{territories}|see{vùng đất}}
\index{vùng đất} % a correction

% For purpose of this post...
\begingroup
\def\thispagestyle#1{}
\printindex[authors]

\def\indexname{Topic index} % The imakeidx is not working for me at its best...
\printindex
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

This is the `vietnamesemal-test.xdy` file and finally this is the `vietnamesemal.xdy` file (both generated by `xindy-make-rules`). I tried my best to post them here, but the second generated file contains some characters which weren't displayed correctly here and therefore it is not working in `xindy` then, please download them, e.g. by:

> wget http://striz7.fame.utb.cz/tex-sx/vietnamesemal-test.xdy
>   wget http://striz7.fame.utb.cz/tex-sx/vietnamesemal.xdy

I also post the TeX file (just in case) and the PDF file (if you would like to zoom in the pages), you can get the files by:

> wget http://striz7.fame.utb.cz/tex-sx/IndexVietnamese.tex
>   wget http://striz7.fame.utb.cz/tex-sx/IndexVietnamese.pdf

[image: Author index, a working example]

[image: Topic index, a working example]

Comment: Just as reference: See also [How to sort alphabet index in Vietnamese correctly?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131356) and https://github.com/michal-h21/iec2utf.

Comment: Please inform the `xindy` developer.

Comment: Could you give a solution for Linux? I can not get it work after edited as your suggestion and rerun the make install. It is still sorted as if it has been modified. That would be great if you can provide way to work with texlua as follow.

`#!/usr/bin/env sh
texlua iec2utf.lua T5 < basename $1 .tex.idx | texindy -i -M lang/vietnamese/utf8-lang -o basename $1 .tex.ind `

Comment: @user39400 I am not using `make install` in my example because for purpose of this post I edited `alphabets-doc.tex` and it wouldn't be working on other languages. I can add `vietnamesemal.xdy` and `vietnamesemal-test.xdy` to the post, so you could just download and use them. I am on it.

Comment: @Malipivo Excellent. Is there any reasons for using `lualatex` instead of `inputenc` and `babel` packages? I am trying on my document, after running `lualatex --shell-escape IndexVietnamese.tex` then the index order is messed up as expected. But when running `xindy -M vietnamesemal-test -M malstyle IndexVietnamese.idx` and then `lualatex --shell-escape IndexVietnamese.tex`, the Index sections are just empty. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @user39400 I haven't tested that as I focused on rearranging tonal diacritics in the file for `xindy`, I am not sure if `inputenc` could handle all those characters. I am using `-M tex/inputenc/cp1250` when dealing with `babel`, `czech` option and `pdflatex`, I can try that approach. I would rather use that `iec2utf.lua` snippet, it might cover more letters. Yes, there is, `xelatex` and `lualatex` can handle UTF-8 characters without `inputenc`, then the generated `idx` file doesn't contain TeX sequences. Would you mind and post your file in your Question? I can take a look at it.