# Makeindex without sorting

Tags: indexing, sorting, xindy

Can I use `makeindex` but without sorting? This question looks peculiar but I would like to use index while the index entries (for example `\index{Peace}` in the document) are already sorted correctly according to Icelandic alphabet. The reason is that `xindy` sorting of Icelandic (for now) is incorrect ([according to this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165273/8380))

Comment: Do you mean you already have a generated (or hand written) index file? In which case you don't need an external program at all, latex will just input it.

Comment: No. I have edited the question. I hope it is now clear.

Comment: You mean that the occurrences of `\index` _in the document_ are in order? So it's not an index? Please (always) include a complete small document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear but if I take the MWE from the linked question and add ascii approximations to the strings before `@` then makeindex sorts as required. (I may have the sort order wrong but the idea is that if the order is  A Á B then change Á to anything that sorts between A and B (say A1) and put the mangled string before `@` so it is only used for sorting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{makeidx}
\usepackage[icelandic, czech]{babel}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
Hello
\index{z1ari@Þari - Franz Eugen Kohler, Public Domain}
\index{z1istill@Þistill - ŠARŽÍK František, COPYRIGHT/PD}
\index{O2nd@Önd - Karney, Lee, PD}
\index{a3d@Æðarkóngur - Whitehouse, Laura L., PD}
\index{Avo1@Avókadó - Forest \& Kim [[p:2684;Starr]], CC-BY}
\index{Aud1@Auðnutittlingur - Arnstein Rønning, CC BY-SA 3.0}
\index{Asni@Asni - Zicha Ondřej, COPYRIGHT/CC-BY-NC}
\index{A1@Á - hvalur.org, CC Unported Licence}
\index{A1lft@Álft - Bukovský Jiří, COPYRIGHT/CC-BY-NC}
\index{A1lka@Álka - Jack Spellingbacon from Scotland, CC BY-SA 3.0}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is very interesting idea! Mangled string could be first letter + increased number.. !? One last think - does `makeindex` recognise the **á** (í, ó, ý, ú, é) letter as a separate letter in index? If not, how can we force him to recognize?

Comment: makeindex is basically ascii use a1 for  á  if you want it sorted after a similarly for other accented letters. Use the same ascii string for each occurrence of the letter, you don't want an "increasing number"  This is assuming that you do in fact want sorting in your real case. If you don't want sorting and just want to print a list in the order that it is in the file, just use latex (eg a description environment) `\item[]` instead of `\index{}`. and no makeindex or xindy is needed.

Comment: Exactly - I dont want sorting, but I would like to use the page number (with hyperlink) that enables user to visit the page the index entry (in index) shows.

Comment: @chejnik Well OK but you could just use `\pageref` for that and not need any external files or indexing program.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will wait until the bug in xindy is repaired.

Comment: We could prepare a special `xdy` file with modified sorting rules if you are not satisfied with present settings in the `xdy` file for Icelandic language. There is just a couple of steps needed, see an example of correction of tonal diacritics in Vietnamese, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168197/48028

Answer (score 1):

> Not recommended

Just in case if someone is in need of creating an index without sorting in `xindy`. I am adding a number from counter to the index terms and they become a part of sorting process. We lose letter groups anyway.

> lualatex mal-xindy-nosorting.tex
>   xindy -M texindy -M makeindex mal-xindy-nosorting.idx
>   lualatex mal-xindy-nosorting.tex

The generated `idx` looks like this:

```
\indexentry{1 dog@dog|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{2 mouse@mouse|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{3 horse@horse|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{4 cat@cat|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{5 bird@bird|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{6 girafa@girafa|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{7 zebra@zebra|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{8 jellyfish@jellyfish|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{9 lion@lion|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{10 cow@cow|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{11 octopus@octopus|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{12 ant@ant|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{13 worm@worm|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{14 wolf@wolf|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{15 owl@owl|hyperpage}{1}
```

And the content of the `ind` file is this:

```
\begin{theindex}
  \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
  \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
      \par\textbf{#1}\par
      \nopagebreak
  }

  \lettergroupDefault{default}
  \item dog, \hyperpage{1}
  \item mouse, \hyperpage{1}
  \item horse, \hyperpage{1}
  \item cat, \hyperpage{1}
  \item bird, \hyperpage{1}
  \item girafa, \hyperpage{1}
  \item zebra, \hyperpage{1}
  \item jellyfish, \hyperpage{1}
  \item lion, \hyperpage{1}
  \item cow, \hyperpage{1}
  \item octopus, \hyperpage{1}
  \item ant, \hyperpage{1}
  \item worm, \hyperpage{1}
  \item wolf, \hyperpage{1}
  \item owl, \hyperpage{1}

\end{theindex}
```

I also enclose the `tex` file and a preview of page 2 in `pdf`:

```
%! *latex mal-xindy-nosorting.tex
%! xindy -M texindy -M makeindex mal-xindy-nosorting.idx
%! *latex mal-xindy-nosorting.tex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
The first paragraph of text.
\let\oldindex=\index
\newcount\malcount \malcount=0
\def\index#1{\advance\malcount by 1%
  \oldindex{\the\malcount\space#1@#1}%
  }% End of \index redefinition...
\index{dog}\index{mouse}\index{horse}
\index{cat}\index{bird}\index{girafa}\index{zebra}
\index{jellyfish}\index{lion}\index{cow}\index{octopus}
\index{ant}\index{worm}\index{wolf}\index{owl}
\begingroup\def\thispagestyle#1{}\printindex\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]