# Disable sorting in texindy

Tags: pdftex, indexing, unicode, sorting, xindy

I'm trying to establish a workflow for a LaTeX project and haven't figured out how to use makeidx or imakeidx packages to sort UTF-8 encoded index by languages not covered in the section [supported languages/codepages of texindy](http://www.xindy.org/doc/texindy-man.pdf).

So I decide to run my main tex file with `\makeindex` in the preamble and wrote a script <sup>[1]</sup> that overwrites the .idx file to my liking.

Now I have to convert the .idx into .ind, but everytime I invoke makeindex or texindy they output .ind files that changes the order specified in my .idx file.

1. Is there a way to ask makeindex or texindy to generate .ind file in accordance to the order of entries specified in the .idx file?
2. Is there a way to provide custom groups that are not really based on letters, preferably by further modifying the .idx file or calling texindy?  I realize that `\lettergroup` exists.

---

<sup>[1]: Locale-aware sorting of tuples by first splitting each row in .idx by '!'</sup>

Comment: Just found [a relevant answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165478/makeindex-without-sorting?rq=1). Seems like it's worth a try. I'll post the script if this new idea works.