# Can the comma in the index be replaced by another character?

Tags: indexing, xindy

I am looking for a simple solution to change index entries so that I get `honey • 24` instead of `honey, 24`. I looked through a couple of articles on influencing the index style ([idxlayout customized delimiters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477447/idxlayout-customized-delimiters), [Is there an easy way to hide comma (,) from the end of the indexed words?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197042/is-there-an-easy-way-to-hide-comma-from-the-end-of-the-indexed-words)) but it seems that I am not advanced enough to make use of those ideas.

**EDIT: I am looking explicitly for a `xindy` solution, i.e. how to make or change a (which?) `*.xdy` file.**

Here's an MWE with all the preamble stuff (I left more or less everything important):

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,titlepage,headsepline,headings=small,BCOR=17mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} % scrpage2
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[vietnamese=nohyphenation]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage[vietnamese,polish]{babel}
\usepackage[T5,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[columns=2,itemlayout=abshang,initsep=1.8em plus 0.2em minus 0.2em]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\rawindex}[1]{\expandafter\index\expandafter{\detokenize{#1}}}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

Some text \rawindex{text} is written \rawindex{text!more text} here. What \rawindex{hello} do you think of me?

\backmatter
    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{INDEKS}
    \ihead[]{}
    \sffamily
\setindexprenote{Hello!}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Does anyone have an idea of a simple solution for the needed change?

Comment: Would you please try to make your example a bit more "minimal"? I have the impression that most of the code is irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: @campa Thanks for the hint. I left however more details in my "MWE", because there's an issue with correct sorting of index entries. They're in Vietnamese and therefore I use a workaround with that rawindex thing and then I have it properly sorted by xindy.

Answer (score 1):

With a more MWE…

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[columns=2,itemlayout=abshang,initsep=1.8em plus 0.2em minus 0.2em]{idxlayout}

\makeindex

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.mst}
delim_0 " $\\cdot$  "
delim_1 " $\\cdot$  "
delim_2 " $\\cdot$  "
delim_n ", "
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \mainmatter
    
    Some text \index{text} is written \index{text!more text} here. What \index{hello} do you think of me?
    
    \clearpage
    Text\index{text}
    
    \backmatter
    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{INDEKS}
    \sffamily
    \setindexprenote{Hello!}
    \printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: I keep the comma between pages with `delim_n`

Comment: I just tried to implement this, but it seems not working. I left more details in my "MWE", because there's an issue with correct sorting of index entries. They're in Vietnamese and therefore I use a workaround with that `rawindex` thing and then I have it properly sorted by xindy. Can you think of adding something to my big "MWE" for the desired result without having to change the way the indexing is done?

Comment: Could it be that the `*.mst`-file doesn't work with xindy?

Comment: Using your code (I just remove the `\usepackage[T5,T1]{fontenc}`) compiles fine here with `lualatex` + `makeindex`… I never use `xindy`. Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198318/customize-xindy-index-layout

Comment: The problem was that only `xindy` was able to sort Vietnamese properly. I had it discussed a couple of years ago i.a. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252407/index-sorting-problems-with-vietnamese). I've been more or less off the topic since then, so I don't really recall details of that any more. :-(

Comment: I already before had a look at the link you provided, but as far as I remember that sadly wouldn't work for Vietnamese.

Comment: For what I understand, we have to setup a `xdy` file instead of the `mst`. But I don't know what to write in it…

Comment: Thanks, good direction. I edited the question hence to make it more clear.