# My glossary won't print

Tags: glossaries

I'm having trouble for 2 days printing a glossary (using glossaries package). I tried on TexLive and TexMaker.

I followed this [documentation/tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary) to understand how to use glossaries package

Here is my test source code to print a glossary:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
    \newglossaryentry{computer} {
        name=computer,
        description={is a programmable machine that receives input,
           stores and manipulates data, and provides
           output in a useful format}
    }
    \gls{computer}
    \printglossaries
\end{document}
```

To make the glossary I read that I had to make a custom user command in TexMaker:

> makeglossaries %

[image]

Si I build with PDFLatex, it builds without any error, then run the custom command but I got this error:

> Process started
>
> Process exited with error(s)

Additionnal information:

> The compilation created .aux, .glo, .glsdefs, .ist, .log, .pdf, .synctex, .tex files
>
> Perl installed
>
> TexMaker 4.2

I'm kind of stuck here, I've no idea what to do.

Thank you

**Edit n°3:** when typing

> makeglossaries testGlossaire

In a prompt, I got this error message:

> C:\texlive\2013\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:671: C:\texlive\2013\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:641: program not found (not part of TeX Live): cmd

So I looked at runscript.tlu and found the function which returned this message:

```
-- checks if command exists on the path and returns its full path
local function check_command(cmdlist, PATH)
  for cmd in string.gmatch(cmdlist, '%S+') do
    local cmdext = cmd..(string.find(cmd, '%.[^\\/.]*$') and '' or '.exe')
    local fullcmd = search_path(cmdext, PATH)
    if fullcmd then 
      return fullcmd, cmd
    end
  end
  return nil, 'program not found (not part of TeX Live): '..cmdlist
end
```

**Edit n°2:** added an image to show the custom command

**Edit n°1:** the full log (content of the .log file):

> ! This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX) (format=pdflatex 2014.6.6)  10 JUN 2014 10:53
>   ! entering extended mode
>   !  restricted \write18 enabled.
>   !  %&-line parsing enabled.
>   ! **testGlossaire.tex
>   ! (./testGlossaire.tex
>   ! LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
>   ! Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
>   ! Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
>   ! File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
>   ! )
>   ! \c@part=\count79
>   ! \c@chapter=\count80
>   ! \c@section=\count81
>   ! \c@subsection=\count82
>   ! \c@subsubsection=\count83
>   ! \c@paragraph=\count84
>   ! \c@subparagraph=\count85
>   ! \c@figure=\count86
>   ! \c@table=\count87
>   ! \abovecaptionskip=\skip41
>   ! \belowcaptionskip=\skip42
>   ! \bibindent=\dimen102
>   ! )
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries.sty
>   ! Package: glossaries 2014/04/04 v4.07 (NLCT)
>   ! 
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
>   ! Package: ifthen 2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
>   ! )
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
>   ! Package: xkeyval 2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
>   ! 
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
>   ! \XKV@toks=\toks14
>   ! \XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15
>   ! \XKV@depth=\count88
>   ! File: xkeyval.tex 2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
>   ! 
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/mfirstuc.sty
>   ! Package: mfirstuc 2013/11/04 v1.08 (NLCT)
>   ! 
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
>   ! Package: etoolbox 2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
>   ! 
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty
>   ! Package: etex 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
>   ! \et@xins=\count89
>   ! )
>   ! \etb@tempcnta=\count90
>   ! )
>   ! \@glsmfirst=\toks16
>   ! \@glsmrest=\toks17
>   ! )
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty
>   ! Package: textcase 2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
>   ! )
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xfor/xfor.sty
>   ! Package: xfor 2009/02/05 v1.05 (NLCT)
>   ! )
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-base.sty
>   ! Package: datatool-base 2013/09/06 v2.18 (NLCT)
>   ! 
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
>   ! Package: amsmath 2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
>   ! \@mathmargin=\skip43
>   ! 
>   ! For additional information on amsmath, use the '?' option.
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
>   ! Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01
>   ! 
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
>   ! File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
>   ! \@emptytoks=\toks18
>   ! \ex@=\dimen103
>   ! ))
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
>   ! Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d
>   ! \pmbraise@=\dimen104
>   ! )
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
>   ! Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
>   ! )
>   ! \inf@bad=\count91
>   ! LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 210.
>   ! \uproot@=\count92
>   ! \leftroot@=\count93
>   ! LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 306.
>   ! \classnum@=\count94
>   ! \DOTSCASE@=\count95
>   ! LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 378.
>   ! LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 381.
>   ! LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 466.
>   ! \Mathstrutbox@=\box26
>   ! \strutbox@=\box27
>   ! \big@size=\dimen105
>   ! LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 566.
>   ! LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 567.
>   ! \macc@depth=\count96
>   ! \c@MaxMatrixCols=\count97
>   ! \dotsspace@=\muskip10
>   ! \c@parentequation=\count98
>   ! \dspbrk@lvl=\count99
>   ! \tag@help=\toks19
>   ! \row@=\count100
>   ! \column@=\count101
>   ! \maxfields@=\count102
>   ! \andhelp@=\toks20
>   ! \eqnshift@=\dimen106
>   ! \alignsep@=\dimen107
>   ! \tagshift@=\dimen108
>   ! \tagwidth@=\dimen109
>   ! \totwidth@=\dimen110
>   ! \lineht@=\dimen111
>   ! \@envbody=\toks21
>   ! \multlinegap=\skip44
>   ! \multlinetaggap=\skip45
>   ! \mathdisplay@stack=\toks22
>   ! LaTeX Info: Redefining [ on input line 2665.
>   ! LaTeX Info: Redefining ] on input line 2666.
>   ! )
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/substr/substr.sty
>   ! Package: substr 2009/10/20 v1.2 Handle substrings
>   ! \c@su@anzahl=\count103
>   ! )
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-fp.sty
>   ! Package: datatool-fp 2013/08/29 v2.17 (NLCT)
>   ! 
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty
>   ! Package: fp 1995/04/02
>   ! 
>   ! 'Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/defpattern.sty
>   ! Package: defpattern 1994/10/12
>   ! \actioncount=\count104
>   ! )
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty
>   ! Package: fp-basic 1996/05/13
>   ! \FP@xs=\count105
>   ! \FP@xia=\count106
>   ! \FP@xib=\count107
>   ! \FP@xfa=\count108
>   ! \FP@xfb=\count109
>   ! \FP@rega=\count110
>   ! \FP@regb=\count111
>   ! \FP@regs=\count112
>   ! \FP@times=\count113
>   ! )
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-addons.sty
>   ! Package: fp-addons 1995/03/15
>   ! )
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty
>   ! Package: fp-snap 1995/04/05
>   ! )
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-exp.sty
>   ! Package: fp-exp 1995/04/03
>   ! )
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-trigo.sty
>   ! Package: fp-trigo 1995/04/14
>   ! )
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-pas.sty
>   ! Package: fp-pas 1994/08/29
>   ! )
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-random.sty
>   ! Package: fp-random 1995/02/23
>   ! \FPseed=\count114
>   ! )
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty
>   ! Package: fp-eqn 1995/04/03
>   ! )
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty
>   ! Package: fp-upn 1996/10/21
>   ! )
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty
>   ! Package: fp-eval 1995/04/03
>   ! )))
>   ! \@dtl@toks=\toks23
>   ! \@dtl@tmpcount=\count115
>   ! \dtl@tmplength=\skip46
>   ! \dtl@sortresult=\count116
>   ! \@dtl@numgrpsepcount=\count117
>   ! \@dtl@datatype=\count118
>   ! \dtl@codeA=\count119
>   ! \dtl@codeB=\count120
>   ! \@dtl@foreach@level=\count121
>   ! )
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries-compatible-307
>   ! .sty
>   ! Package: glossaries-compatible-307 2013/11/14 v4.0 (NLCT)
>   ! )
>   ! \gls@level=\count122
>   ! \@gls@tmpb=\toks24
>   ! \gls@tmplen=\skip47
>   ! \glskeylisttok=\toks25
>   ! \glslabeltok=\toks26
>   ! \glsshorttok=\toks27
>   ! \glslongtok=\toks28
>   ! 
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-hypernav.sty
>   ! Package: glossary-hypernav 2013/11/14 v4.0 (NLCT)
>   ! )
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-list.sty
>   ! Package: glossary-list 2013/11/14 v4.0 (NLCT)
>   ! \glslistdottedwidth=\skip48
>   ! )
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-long.sty
>   ! Package: glossary-long 2013/11/14 v4.0 (NLCT)
>   ! 
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty
>   ! Package: longtable 2004/02/01 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
>   ! \LTleft=\skip49
>   ! \LTright=\skip50
>   ! \LTpre=\skip51
>   ! \LTpost=\skip52
>   ! \LTchunksize=\count123
>   ! \LTcapwidth=\dimen112
>   ! \LT@head=\box28
>   ! \LT@firsthead=\box29
>   ! \LT@foot=\box30
>   ! \LT@lastfoot=\box31
>   ! \LT@cols=\count124
>   ! \LT@rows=\count125
>   ! \c@LT@tables=\count126
>   ! \c@LT@chunks=\count127
>   ! \LT@p@ftn=\toks29
>   ! )
>   ! \glsdescwidth=\skip53
>   ! \glspagelistwidth=\skip54
>   ! )
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-super.sty
>   ! Package: glossary-super 2013/11/14 v4.0 (NLCT)
>   ! 
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/supertabular/supertabular.sty
>   ! Package: supertabular 2004/02/20 v4.1e the supertabular environment
>   ! \c@tracingst=\count128
>   ! \ST@wd=\dimen113
>   ! \ST@rightskip=\skip55
>   ! \ST@leftskip=\skip56
>   ! \ST@parfillskip=\skip57
>   ! \ST@pageleft=\dimen114
>   ! \ST@headht=\dimen115
>   ! \ST@tailht=\dimen116
>   ! \ST@pagesofar=\dimen117
>   ! \ST@pboxht=\dimen118
>   ! \ST@lineht=\dimen119
>   ! \ST@stretchht=\dimen120
>   ! \ST@prevht=\dimen121
>   ! \ST@toadd=\dimen122
>   ! \ST@dimen=\dimen123
>   ! \ST@pbox=\box32
>   ! ))
>   ! (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-tree.sty
>   ! Package: glossary-tree 2014/03/06 v4.04 (NLCT)
>   ! \glstreeindent=\skip58
>   ! ))
>   ! \glswrite=\write3
>   ! \glo@main@file=\write4
>   ! \openout4 = 'testGlossaire.glo'.
>   ! 
>   ! Package glossaries Info: Writing glossary file testGlossaire.glo on input line 
>   ! 9.
>   ! 
>   ! (./testGlossaire.aux)
>   ! \openout1 = 'testGlossaire.aux'.
>   ! 
>   ! LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 11.
>   ! LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
>   ! LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
>   ! LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
>   ! LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
>   ! LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
>   ! LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 11.
>   ! LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
>   ! LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 11.
>   ! LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
>   ! LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
>   ! LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
>   !  (./testGlossaire.glsdefs)
>   ! No file testGlossaire.gls.
>   ! [1
>   ! 
>   ! \openout3 = 'testGlossaire.ist'.
>   ! 
>   ! {c:/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
>   ! (./testGlossaire.aux) ) 
>   ! Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
>   !  4637 strings out of 493308
>   !  65418 string characters out of 6141368
>   !  172346 words of memory out of 5000000
>   !  8048 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
>   !  3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
>   !  957 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
>   !  46i,4n,39p,1774b,111s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
>   ! 
>   ! Output written on testGlossaire.pdf (1 page, 11913 bytes).
>   ! PDF statistics:
>   !  12 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
>   !  7 compressed objects within 1 object stream
>   !  0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
>   ! 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us the custom command you have used!

Comment: Hello, it's: "makeglossaries %" I've written it, I'll make it more visible

Comment: Please open a terminal in your main folder. Run `pdflatex MWE.tex`, then `makeglossaries MWE`, and then again `pdflatex MWE.tex` (MWE has to be replaced by the actual name). This works perfectly here.

Comment: And make sure, you are doing everything like explained here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61102. It sounds like you are doing that, but maybe this tutorial shows you some error on your process.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I got this error with makeglossaries: C:\texlive\2013\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:671: C:\texlive\2013\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:641: program not found (not part of TeX Live): cmd

Comment: Do you have Perl installed? (By the way, I recommend you move `\newglossaryentry` into the preamble as it can cause problems using it in the `document` environment. See [Drawbacks With Defining Entries in the Document Environment](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs).)

Comment: Actually, I see you're using TeX Live, so you should have the Perl interpreter that comes with it.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I followed this [tutorial](http://learn.perl.org/installing/windows.html) to install Perl, so I guess I have it installed. I ran Perl -v in the perl console and it gave me the perl version etc. Thank you for the information about \newglossaryentry

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I added an image to show the custom user command

Comment: Try replacing `makeglossaries` with `makeglossaries.bat` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Tried to in a windows shell and I got: " 'makeglossaries.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Comment: Ok so I look at runscript.tlu and ctrl+f "program not found (not part of TeX Live)" and there's a function doing this. Editing my post.

Comment: It sounds like either you're missing the `makeglossaries` script or it's not on your path. I don't use Windows so I can't help any further. It should be in the `bin` directory (same as `runscript.tlu`) but it may be in `C:\texlive\2013\texmf-dist\scripts\glossaries` (or similar).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Indeed, I had this path missing in my environment variables. Everything is finally working! Thank you. Post it as answer so I can mark my question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PATH environment variable was missing the directory where the `makeglossaries` script is located. Once the directory is on the path, `runscript.tlu` should be able to find it.