# Customize xindy index layout

Tags: indexing, xindy, imakeidx

I am making a songbook, using the `songs` package. The book is in norwegian, and thus we need the norwegian letters æ,ø,å to be indexed after z. As far as i understand, this is only possible with the xindy package. Creating the index is no problem, but I want to customize how it looks. As pr. now, it looks like this:

[image: Current layout]

Using makeindex, I was able to make it look correct
[image: Correct layout]

Here is the code for makeindex

```
\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx} % Normal LaTeX indexing
\makeindex[columns=1, title=Sangregister,program=makeindex,intoc=true,options=-s idxconf.ist] % Properties of index
```

This is for xindy

```
\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx} 
\def\xindylangopt{-M lang/norwegian/latin1-test }
\makeindex[columns=1,name=master,title =Sangregister,intoc=true,options=\xindylangopt]
```

The layout-options, is in the file `idxconf.ist`, which works on `makeindex` looks like this

```
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\bfseries "
heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak\n"
delim_0 " \\dotfill "
delim_1 " \\dotfill "
delim_2 " \\dotfill "
```

Is it possible to use the idxconf.ist file with xindy? If not, how do I customize xindy to look like the last picture.

Here is a minimum working example:

xindy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}
\def\xindylangopt{-M lang/norwegian/latin1-test}
\makeindex[columns=1,name=xindytest,title =Sangregister,  options=\xindylangopt]
\begin{document}
start
\index{a}\index{æ}\index{ø}\index{å}
end
blabla
\printindex
\end{document}
```

makeindex, which looks correct, but æøå is treated as symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=1, title=Sangregister,program=makeindex,intoc=true,options=-s idxconf.ist] % Egenskaper til indeks
\begin{document}
start
\index{a}\index{æ}\index{ø}\index{å}
end
blabla
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Oh yes, here is a MWE

`

Comment: From [my answer to another question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199841/) it seems that for Danish `texindy` results in a different alphabetical ordering to that produced using `xindy -I xindy`. Perhaps the same is occurring with Norwegian.

Answer (score 10):

For a smilar work, in italian (songbook with songs beginning with accented letters) I used this style file (`indicealfabetico.xdy`)

```
 (markup-index :open  "\begin{theindex}\sffamily~n
 \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
 \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
 \par\textbf{\large#1}\par
   \nopagebreak
  }"
          :close "~n~n\end{theindex}~n"
          :tree)


;; The indexentries (item_<..> specifiers)

(markup-indexentry :open "~n  \item "           :depth 0)
(markup-indexentry :open "~n    \subitem "     :depth 1)
(markup-indexentry :open "~n      \subsubitem " :depth 2)

;; Location-references

;; delim_0 <string>         ", "
;; delim_1 <string>         ", "
;; delim_2 <string>         ", "

(markup-locclass-list :open "\dotfill " :sep ", ")

;; delim_n <string>         ", "

(markup-locref-list   :sep ", ")

;; delim_r <string>         "--"

(markup-range :sep "--")
```

using xindy in this way:

```
% arara: xelatex: { shell : yes }
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx} 
\makeindex[name=alfabetico,title=Indice alfabetico,program=truexindy,options=-M texindy -C utf8 -L italian -M indicealfabetico]
```

A compilable example, that works with xelatex:

```
% arara: xelatex: { shell : yes}
\begin{filecontents*}{style.xdy}
(markup-index :open  "\begin{theindex}\sffamily~n
 \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
 \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
 \par\textbf{\large#1}\par
   \nopagebreak
  }"
          :close "~n~n\end{theindex}~n"
          :tree)

(markup-locclass-list :open "\dotfill " :sep ", ")
;; End
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=1,title=Sangregister,program=truexindy,options=-M texindy -C utf8 -L norwegian -M style]
\begin{document}
start
\index{a}\index{æ}\index{ø}\index{å}\index{Song}
end
blabla
\printindex
\end{document}
```

That gives:[image]

Answer (score 6):

Not entirely shure I answer your question sufficiently, but using the provided MWE I created the desired result  using the "glossaries" package instead of trying to tweak "imakeidx".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\renewcommand*\glspostdescription{\dotfill}      % Dotted line to page numbers
\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textnormal{#1}} % No bold font on index names

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\newglossaryentry{a}{name={a},description={}}
\newglossaryentry{ae}{name = {{æ}},description = {}} %Improtant to note the double curly
\newglossaryentry{oe}{name = {{ø}},description = {}} %brackets around the special caracters,
\newglossaryentry{aa}{name = {{å}},description = {}} %and only ASCII (afaik) in the handle.

start \gls{ae} \gls{aa} \gls{oe} \gls{a}
end
blabla

\printglossary[style=indexgroup, title=Sangregister]
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image: LaTeX xindy glossary result]

I commented the places where I thought an explanation would be needed. I recommend reading the user documentation found here: [CTAN Glossaries](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries).

In case you're using MiKTeX, and haven't already fully installed xindy and pearl, I recommed these three posts from user Speravir:

- [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex/69484#69484)
- [How to use Xindy with MiKTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71167/how-to-use-xindy-with-miktex/71168#71168)
- [MiKTeX and Perl scripts (and one Python script)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158796/miktex-and-perl-scripts-and-one-python-script)

If you're using TeXmaker (or one of its derivatives): Here's a good answer to where to add the "makeglossaries" command:

- [Using Texmaker with glossaries on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61099/using-texmaker-with-glossaries-on-windows)

Hope this helps!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Thanks!
Forgot to mention that it is important to recompile after running makeglossaries ...

Answer (score 1):

I made some minor edits to Francesco's answer.

- I use the overwrite option for the filecontents environment so that
  my formatting changes are saved.
- You don't need `(markup-index ...)` in the form given here, since this
  is the default.
- The separator in the reference list is set by `(markup-locref-list :sep "; ")`
  and not by the `:sep` variable of  `(markup-locclass-list :open "\dotfill " :sep ", ")`.
- Add a language package like polyglossia in luatex or babel in pdftex to get the local term for "see", e.g., "Sjå" in
  Norwegian.

So my modified version is as follows.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TeX spellcheck = en_NO
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{style.xdy}
(markup-locclass-list :open "\dotfill ")
(markup-locref-list            :sep "; ")
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[babelshorthands=true]{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{norwegian}
\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=1,title=Sangregister,options= -C utf8 -L norwegian  -M style]
\begin{document}
  a\index{a}, æ\index{æ}, ø\index{ø}, å\index{å}, Song\index{Song}\newpage
  a\index{a}, æ\index{æ}, ø\index{ø}, å\index{å}, Lied\index{Lied|see{Song}}
  \printindex
\end{document
```

Comment: Appreciate the comment. Although the project was completed 6 years ago 

Comment: Thank you. I had to learn the usefulness of the option overwrite the hard way. I changed the content and nothing happened until I added this option.