# Differences between "xindy" and "makeindex"

Tags: indexing, xindy

I'd like to know which are the *essential differences* between `makeindex` and `xindy` (or `texindy`) in this sense:

- What things can we do with `xindy` that we can not do with `makeindex`? or vice versa.
- What is the primary use of each one of them?
- Syntactic differences between their *style files*. (`.ist` vs `.xdy`)

Comment: Most important: Xindy supports unicode and other languages apart of English. So if you want to sort something with accents properly, you will have to take `xindy` for that. For that, I would say, one should always prefer `xindy` over `makeindex` BUT: `xindy` requires shell-escape in order to run which is making `makeindex` easier, more compatible (and maybe safer, if you fear to escape...).

Comment: @LaRiFaRi  `xindy` only require shell-escape if you want to run it from LaTeX it self. I'm personally not a fan of running external programs from LaTeX. As for the last item in the list. There are very large differences in how they are configured. However the `xindy` default often suit people better than the `makeindex` default, e.g. `xindy` provide letter groups, which is a configuration add-on in `makeindex`

Comment: I think this Q calls for a really good answer one can use as a *link-to reference*.

Comment: The [`xindy` FAQ](http://xindy.sourceforge.net/doc/faq-1.html#ss1.2) discusses some differences.

Comment: Others contributions at this question are welcome.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

## Short Answer

`xindy` is far more flexible than `makeindex`. Unlike `makeindex`, `xindy` supports UTF8, can sort according to different language rules and can support enumeration systems outside of the European and Roman numbering systems. The UTF8 support works best with `xindy -I xindy` rather than with `texindy` (`xindy -I latex`).

## Long Answer

> What things can we do with `xindy` that we can not do with `makeindex`?

The [xindy FAQ](http://xindy.sourceforge.net/doc/faq-1.html#ss1.2) provides a useful summary of the things `xindy` can do that can't be done with `makeindex`. Here's an abridged form of that summary:

> ### Internationalization
>
> `xindy` can be configured to process indexes for many languages with
> different letter sets and different sorting rules. [`makeindex` is
> hard-coded for the English alphabet.]
>
> ### Location classes
>
> `makeindex` is able to recognize and process arabic numbers, roman
> numerals and letter-based alphabets as specifiers for the indexed
> location. Simple composite structures of these are also possible to
> process. `xindy` provides a powerful declaration scheme called
> *location-classes*. [This means you can have locations in a completely different numbering scheme (for example, hieroglyph numerals).]
>
> ### The concept of attributes
>
> With `makeindex` one can assign a markup to each index entry using the
> encapsulators (usually following the vertical bar sign in an index
> entry command). For example in the specification
>
> ```
> \index{xindy|bold}
> ```
>
> the encapsulator is bold which encapsulates the page-numbers in the
> markup-phase. An additional TeX-macro must be supplied to assign some
> markup with the page number. This concept has completely been dropped
> in `xindy` in favour of a more powerful scheme called attributes.
> Attributes can be used to (i) define several grouping and ordering
> rules with locations and we can define (ii) markup-tags for the
> document preparation system.
>
> ### Cross references
>
> Cross-references were implemented in `makeindex` with the
> encapsulation mechanism, which only served for markup purposes. This
> has been completely separated in `xindy`.

In addition to the above, another thing that you can do with `xindy` but not with `makeindex` is to have arbitrary sub-levels. With `makeindex` you're restricted to primary (level 0), first sub-level and second sub-level entries.

> or vice versa.

The only advantages of `makeindex` over `xindy` that I can think of are:

- `makeindex` should be installed with all TeX installations. A TeX installation that doesn't have `makeindex` is most likely extremely old. However, `xindy` is only included in TeX Live so MikTeX users will need to install it separately.
- `xindy` is a Perl script and so you must have the Perl interpreter installed on your computer. This is a stumbling block for some Windows users. Unix-like systems tend to have Perl preinstalled.
- `makeindex` usually works with restricted `\write18` but last time I tried calling `xindy` with a restricted `\write18` it was disabled. I expect it will eventually be added to the list of allowed applications. (I can't see any reason why it shouldn't be allowed.)

> What is the primary use of each one of them?

Sorting and collating. Both read a file that contains a set of terms with an associated location (or cross-reference). The terms are sorted according to the designated alphabet (the English alphabet for `makeindex`, or the chosen alphabet for `xindy`). The term may have a corresponding key that should be used for the actual sort comparison. Multiple occurrences of each term are then merged into a single entry with a sorted *location list*. Consecutive numbering in the location list may be compacted into a number range. This information is then written to another file, which can be input by an application such as `tex` or `latex`. (The output markup can be changed via a style file or module, which means that although `makeindex` and `xindy` are often used with TeX/LaTeX, they can be used with other systems as well.)

> Syntactic differences between their style files. (`.ist` vs `.xdy`)

The syntax of the `.ist` format is much simpler than the `.xdy` format, but this is because it's more restrictive.

### `makeindex` style format (`.ist`)

This is just a list of *⟨specifier⟩* *⟨attribute⟩* pairs. The specifiers are divided into two groups: the input specifiers and the output specifiers.

The input specifiers tell `makeindex` how the input is formatted. Consider the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

Duck\index{duck|textbf}.
Zebra\index{zebra}\index{stripy|see{zebra}}

\newpage

Aardvark\index{aardvark}
Zebra\index{zebra}
\emph{The Rise and Fall of the Duck Empire}%
\index{Rise and Fall of Duck Empire@\emph{The Rise and Fall of the Duck Empire}}%

\newpage

Zebra\index{zebra}
Duck\index{duck}
Aardvark\index{aardvark}
Mallard\index{duck!mallard}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

On the first LaTeX run, a file with the extension `.idx` is created and at the end of the run contains:

```
\indexentry{duck|textbf}{1}
\indexentry{zebra}{1}
\indexentry{stripy|see{zebra}}{1}
\indexentry{aardvark}{2}
\indexentry{zebra}{2}
\indexentry{Rise and Fall of Duck Empire@\emph{The Rise and Fall of the Duck Empire}}{2}
\indexentry{zebra}{3}
\indexentry{duck}{3}
\indexentry{aardvark}{3}
\indexentry{duck!mallard}{3}
```

This is the default format for `makeindex` but can be explicitly set in a `.ist` file using:

```
actual '@'
arg_close '}'
arg_open '{'
encap '|'
keyword '\\indexentry'
level '!'
```

There are some other input specifiers as well. (See [Index Preparation and Processing](http://mirror.ctan.org/indexing/makeindex/paper/ind.pdf).) These specifiers enable `makeindex` to correctly parse the input file.

The output specifiers tell `makeindex` how to format the output. If you run `makeindex` on the above example, the resulting `.ind` file will look like:

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item aardvark, 2, 3

  \indexspace

  \item duck, \textbf{1}, 3
    \subitem mallard, 3

  \indexspace

  \item \emph{The Rise and Fall of the Duck Empire}, 2

  \indexspace

  \item stripy, \see{zebra}{1}

  \indexspace

  \item zebra, 1--3

\end{theindex}
```

This uses the default output specifiers, which include:

```
preamble "\\begin{theindex}\n"
postamble "\n\n\\end{theindex}\n"
group_skip "\n\n  \\indexspace\n"
item_0 "\n  \\item "
item_1 "\n     \\subitem "
delim_0 ", "
delim_1 ", "
```

This `.ind` file can now be input by LaTeX (via `\printindex`). The resulting index looks like:

[image: Image of index]

If I wanted, say, to have headings at the start of each letter group, I can create a file called, say, `test.ist` that contains:

```
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "  \\item\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}\n  \\indexspace\n"
```

Now I need to run `makeindex` with `-s test.ist` which will now write the following to the `.ind` file:

```
\begin{theindex}
  \item\textbf{A}
  \indexspace

  \item aardvark, 2, 3

  \indexspace
  \item\textbf{D}
  \indexspace

  \item duck, \textbf{1}, 3
    \subitem mallard, 3

  \indexspace
  \item\textbf{R}
  \indexspace

  \item \emph{The Rise and Fall of the Duck Empire}, 2

  \indexspace
  \item\textbf{S}
  \indexspace

  \item stripy, \see{zebra}{1}

  \indexspace
  \item\textbf{Z}
  \indexspace

  \item zebra, 1--3

\end{theindex}
```

The next LaTeX run now produces the index:

[image: Image of index]

The reason why the entry "The Rise and Fall of the Duck Empire" is listed in the "R" category rather than the "T" category is because I set the sort key for that entry to "Rise and Fall of Duck Empire".

### `xindy` style format (`.xdy`)

Unlike `makeindex`, `xindy` has modules, which can load other modules, so you can build on existing styles. In addition, `xindy` has an `--input-markup` (`-I`) command line switch that is used to indicate the input markup. There are three supported markup settings: `latex`, `omega` and `xindy`.

#### `xindy -I latex`

Using `texindy` is equivalent to calling `xindy` with `-I latex` and with the modules that enable `xindy` to parse files written using the default `makeindex` input specifiers. So, for example, the above `.idx` file created by LaTeX can be processed directly by `texindy`. If the file is called, say, `test.idx` then `texindy test.idx` will create an `.ind` file that contains:

```
\begin{theindex}
  \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
  \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
      \par\textbf{#1}\par
      \nopagebreak
  }

  \lettergroup{A}
  \item aardvark, 2, 3

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{D}
  \item duck, \textbf{1}, 3
    \subitem mallard, 3

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{R}
  \item \emph{The Rise and Fall of the Duck Empire}, 2

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{S}
  \item stripy, \see{zebra}{}

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{Z}
  \item zebra, 1--3

\end{theindex}
```

This is similar to the `.ind` file created by `makeindex` except that it uses `\lettergroup` to markup the category headings. If this command isn't already defined, it will be defined via `\providecommand` at the start of the `.ind` file. If you want to change the way the heading is formatted, you just need to define `\lettergroup` before `\printindex`. This makes it simpler than the `makeindex` example shown above that needed a custom `.ist` file to make the headings appear.

Writing a `xindy` module is quite complicated and too long to discuss in this (already very long) answer, but the [`xindy` FAQ](http://xindy.sourceforge.net/doc/faq-4.html#ss4.1) gives an introduction. However, there are a number of modules supplied by `xindy` that cover common requirements, in particular the language modules. The modules are in subdirectories of *TEXMF*`/xindy/modules/` where *TEXMF* is the base of the TEXMF tree. The language modules are in *TEXMF*`/xindy/modules/lang/` and are identified via the `-L` command line option.

Suppose my `.idx` file now looks like:

```
\indexentry{ænder|textbf}{1}
\indexentry{zebra}{1}
\indexentry{aardvark}{2}
\indexentry{zebra}{2}
\indexentry{zebra}{3}
\indexentry{ænder}{3}
\indexentry{aardvark}{3}
\indexentry{ænder!gråand}{3}
```

`makeindex` creates the following `.ind` file:

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item aardvark, 2, 3

  \indexspace

  \item zebra, 1--3

  \indexspace

  \item ænder, \textbf{1}, 3
    \subitem gråand, 3

\end{theindex}
```

Here `makeindex` has positioned "ænder" after "zebra". This may not look too bad at first glance if that's the correct position for your language, but now try adding headings by creating an `.ist` file that contains:

```
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "  \\item\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}\n  \\indexspace\n"
```

Running `makeindex` with this style results in:

```
\begin{theindex}
  \item\textbf{A}
  \indexspace

  \item aardvark, 2, 3

  \indexspace
  \item\textbf{Z}
  \indexspace

  \item zebra, 1--3

  \indexspace
  \item\textbf{Ã}
  \indexspace

  \item ÃŠnder, \textbf{1}, 3
    \subitem grÃ¥and, 3

\end{theindex}
```

The UTF8 characters have become mangled as `makeindex` has only grabbed the first octet of æ for the heading. This has ruined the file encoding.

In theory, if I want to use `texindy` instead, I need to specify the language using the `-L` switch (in this case `-L danish`) and the encoding using the `-C` switch (in this case `-C utf8`). Unfortunately this results in the error:

```
(require "tex/inputenc/utf8.xdy")
ERROR: Could not find file "tex/inputenc/utf8.xdy" !
```

and no `.ind` file is produced.

The error goes away if I use `-M lang/danish/utf8`. This results in the `.ind` file containing:

```
\begin{theindex}
  \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
  \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
      \par\textbf{#1}\par
      \nopagebreak
  }

  \lettergroup{A}
  \item aardvark, 2, 3
  \item ænder, \textbf{1}, 3
    \subitem gråand, 3

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{Z}
  \item zebra, 1--3

\end{theindex}
```

which has put "ænder" in the "A" letter group (which is incorrect for the Danish alphabet, see the comment below).

Getting the `.idx` file into the format shown above is somewhat harder. The following XeLaTeX document works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

Ænder\index{ænder|textbf}
Zebra\index{zebra}

\newpage

Aardvark\index{aardvark}
Zebra\index{zebra}

\newpage

Zebra\index{zebra}
Ænder\index{ænder}
Aardvark\index{aardvark}
Gråand\index{ænder!gråand}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

The equivalent LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}

\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

Ænder\index{ænder|textbf}
Zebra\index{zebra}

\newpage

Aardvark\index{aardvark}
Zebra\index{zebra}

\newpage

Zebra\index{zebra}
Ænder\index{ænder}
Aardvark\index{aardvark}
Gråand\index{ænder!gråand}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

produces:

```
\indexentry{\IeC {\ae }nder|textbf}{1}
\indexentry{zebra}{1}
\indexentry{aardvark}{2}
\indexentry{zebra}{2}
\indexentry{zebra}{3}
\indexentry{\IeC {\ae }nder}{3}
\indexentry{aardvark}{3}
\indexentry{\IeC {\ae }nder!gr\IeC {\r a}and}{3}
```

which confuses `texindy`.

#### `xindy -I xindy`

With the `xindy` input markup, the `.idx` file has entries in the format:

```
(indexentry :tkey (("sort" "term") ) :locref "location" :attr "attribute" )
```

where `sort` is the text used by the comparison function when sorting, `term` is how the entry should be typeset in the `.ind` file, `location` is the associated location (page number) for this entry and `attribute` is the associated attribute. This is the format used by the [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package when used with the `xindy` package option.

The differences between the syntax used by `makeindex` and `xindy` can be illustrated by examining the files created using the `glossaries` package.

Consider the following LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}

\usepackage[index,style=indexgroup]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newterm[name={æ}nder]{aender}
\newterm{zebra}
\newterm{aardvark}
\newterm[parent=aender,name=gråand]{graand}

\begin{document}

\Gls[format=textbf]{aender}
\Gls{zebra}

\newpage

\Gls{aardvark}
\Gls{zebra}

\newpage

\Gls{zebra}
\Gls{aender}
\Gls{aardvark}
\Gls{graand}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

This is analogous to the earlier `makeidx` example. By default, this document assumes that `makeindex` will be used. This creates the `.idx` file containing:

```
\glossaryentry{{æ}nder?\glossentry{aender}|setentrycounter[]{page}\textbf}{1}
\glossaryentry{zebra?\glossentry{zebra}|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{1}
\glossaryentry{aardvark?\glossentry{aardvark}|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{2}
\glossaryentry{zebra?\glossentry{zebra}|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{2}
\glossaryentry{zebra?\glossentry{zebra}|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{3}
\glossaryentry{{æ}nder?\glossentry{aender}|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{3}
\glossaryentry{aardvark?\glossentry{aardvark}|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{3}
\glossaryentry{{æ}nder?\glossentry{aender}!gråand?\subglossentry{1}{graand}|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{3}
```

This uses `\glossaryentry` instead of `\indexentry` and the encap character is `?` instead of `@`, so `glossaries` creates a `makeindex` `.ist` file that contains:

```
actual '?'
encap '|'
level '!'
quote '"'
keyword "\\glossaryentry"
preamble "\\glossarysection[\\glossarytoctitle]{\\glossarytitle}\\glossarypreamble\n\\begin{theglossary}\\glossaryheader\n"
postamble "\%\n\\end{theglossary}\\glossarypostamble\n"
group_skip "\\glsgroupskip\n"
item_0 "\%\n"
item_1 "\%\n"
item_2 "\%\n"
item_01 "\%\n"
item_x1 "\\relax \\glsresetentrylist\n"
item_12 "\%\n"
item_x2 "\\relax \\glsresetentrylist\n"
delim_0 "\{\\glossaryentrynumbers\{\\relax "
delim_1 "\{\\glossaryentrynumbers\{\\relax "
delim_2 "\{\\glossaryentrynumbers\{\\relax "
delim_t "\}\}"
delim_n "\\delimN "
delim_r "\\delimR "
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\glsgroupheading\{"
heading_suffix "\}\\relax \\glsresetentrylist "
symhead_positive "glssymbols"
numhead_positive "glsnumbers"
page_compositor "."
suffix_2p ""
suffix_3p ""
```

If, on the other hand, you added the `xindy` package option when you load `glossaries`:

```
\usepackage[index,xindy]{glossaries}
```

The `.idx` file now looks like:

```
(indexentry :tkey (("{æ}nder" "\\glossentry{aender}") ) :locref "{}{1}" :attr "pagetextbf" ) 
(indexentry :tkey (("zebra" "\\glossentry{zebra}") ) :locref "{}{1}" :attr "pageglsnumberformat" ) 
(indexentry :tkey (("aardvark" "\\glossentry{aardvark}") ) :locref "{}{2}" :attr "pageglsnumberformat" ) 
(indexentry :tkey (("zebra" "\\glossentry{zebra}") ) :locref "{}{2}" :attr "pageglsnumberformat" ) 
(indexentry :tkey (("zebra" "\\glossentry{zebra}") ) :locref "{}{3}" :attr "pageglsnumberformat" ) 
(indexentry :tkey (("{æ}nder" "\\glossentry{aender}") ) :locref "{}{3}" :attr "pageglsnumberformat" ) 
(indexentry :tkey (("aardvark" "\\glossentry{aardvark}") ) :locref "{}{3}" :attr "pageglsnumberformat" ) 
(indexentry :tkey (("{æ}nder" "\\glossentry{aender}") ("gråand" "\\subglossentry{1}{graand}") ) :locref "{}{3}" :attr "pageglsnumberformat" )
```

The extended Latin characters, such as å haven't been expanded as they were in the earlier `makeidx` example since, by default, `glossaries` "sanitizes" the sort key. (The reason for the braces around æ is discussed in the UTF8 section of the [`mfirstuc` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mfirstuc/mfirstuc-manual.pdf).)

This time, instead of creating an accompanying `.ist` file, `glossaries` now creates a `xindy` `.xdy` file that is considerable larger, and is too large to reproduce here without exceeding the maximum length of a StackExchange answer. However, if you try the above example yourself, you'll be able to see the syntactic differences.

Running the Perl script `makeglossaries test` (where the example file is called `test.tex`) is equivalent to running `xindy` as:

```
xindy  -L danish -C utf8 -I xindy -M "test" -t "test.ilg" -o "test.ind" "test.idx"
```

Although `-L danish -C utf8` has been used, this now doesn't produce the earlier error with `texindy` as `xindy` is no longer trying to input `tex/inputenc/utf8.xdy`. The index now looks like:

[image: zebra ænder gråand aardvark]

Again, switching to XeLaTeX makes the document simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{danish}

\usepackage[index,style=indexgroup,xindy]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newterm{ænder}
\newterm{zebra}
\newterm{aardvark}
\newterm[parent=ænder]{gråand}

\begin{document}

\Gls[format=textbf]{ænder}
\Gls{zebra}

\newpage

\Gls{aardvark}
\Gls{zebra}

\newpage

\Gls{zebra}
\Gls{ænder}
\Gls{aardvark}
\Gls{gråand}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for this really explanatory answer.

Comment: @Johannes_B This is definitely the longest answer I've posted on TeX.SX :-)

Comment: Thanks for your great work, dedication and effort in this answer!!!

Comment: Nice and very illustrative answer. But as a native Danish speaker I have never ever seen 'æ' sorted under 'a'. Usually you would have the three Scandinavian/Danish characters æ, ø and å as the last three characters of the alphabet and also sorted that way. Therefore you would sort the words "and, zebra, ænder" in that order.

Comment: @Stenskjaer I'm sorry I don't speak Danish. (I couldn't think of any examples in languages that I'm familiar with where the words started with an extended Latin character. I should've asked my Danish friend for advice!) I think you'll have to raise that issue on the `xindy` mailing list.

Comment: @Stenskjaer It seems the incorrect Danish sorting only occurs with `texindy -M lang/danish/utf8`. The sorting is different when used with `xindy -I xindy -L danish -C utf8` (as used in the `glossaries` example). I've edited my answer to show this.

Comment: Great answer. However there is one other major drawback to using Xindy as opposed to MakeIndex: the lack of good tutorials. As far as I'm concerned, this is a good reason for not switching to Xindy.

Comment: @user0 No, `glossaries` requires that all indexed terms must be defined.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot If you are still looking for the words starting with an extended Latin character, simply try out proper names, say, geographic names such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ötztal, or the names of real folks, e.g., the surname of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cem_Özdemir .  Technically, their spelling often remains the same in most Latin languages; in particular, in English you'd write the two example words Ötztal and Özdemir the same way.