# Sorting of bibliography and index

Tags: biblatex, xindy

In the following MWE, I want the bibliography to be sorted by the last name, first name of the first author/editor, and first name, last name of subsequent authors. In the attached image, they are sorted by lastname, first name for all authors, editors, even though subsequent authors are listed as first name last name.

In the index, I want {\"U} to be sorted as U, and not as a separate group.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear-comp,bibstyle=authoryear,hyperref=true,maxcitenames=3,doi=false,url=true,backend=biber,natbib=true,maxbibnames=99,uniquename=false,uniquelist=false,indexing=cite]{biblatex}

\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\newcommand*\lettergroup[1]{}

\makeindex
\usepackage[itemlayout=abshang,indentunit=10pt]{idxlayout}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@article{usami2012some,
  Author =       {Usami, Y and Rana, Thomas},
  Journal =      {Review of Alpha Studies},
  Number =       2,
  Pages =        {74--105},
  Title =        {Some aspects of guarantee},
  Volume =       2,
  Year =         2012
}


@book{benoist2003,
  Editor =       {De Benoist, Bruno and Maria Andersson and Ines Egli
                  and Bahi Takkouche and Henrietta Allen},
  Publisher =    {World Health Organization},
  Location =     {Geneva},
  Title =        {Iodine status worldwide: {WHO} global database on
                  iodine deficiency},
  Url =
                  {whqlibdoc.who.int/publications/2004/9241592001.pdf?ua=1},
  Year =         2004,
  Bdsk-Url-1 =
                  {whqlibdoc.who.int/publications/2004/9241592001.pdf?ua=1}
}

@book{benoist2008,
  Editor =       {De Benoist, Bruno and Erin McLean and Ines Egli and
                  Mary Cogswell},
  Publisher =    {World Health Organization},
  Location =     {Geneva},
  Title =        {Worldwide prevalence of anaemia, 1993--2005: WHO
                  global database on anaemia},
  Url =
                  {whqlibdoc.who.int/publications/2008/9789241596657_eng.pdf},
  Year =         2008,
  Bdsk-Url-1 =
                  {whqlibdoc.who.int/publications/2008/9789241596657_eng.pdf}
}


@article{morris2008effective,
  Author =       {Morris, Saul S. and Cogill, Bruce and Uauy, Ricardo},
  Journal =      {The Lancet},
  Number =       9612,
  Pages =        {608--21},
  Title =        {Effective international action against
                  undernutrition: Why has it proven so difficult and
                  what can be done to accelerate progress?},
  Volume =       371,
  Year =         2008
}

@article{biberanak2002,
  Author =       {Biber, F. Z{\"u}mr{\"u}t and {\"U}nak, Perihan and
                  Yurt, Fatma},
  sortname =    {Biber, F. Zumrut and Unak, Perihan and Yurt, Fatma},
  Doi =          {10.1080/10256010208033316},
  Journal =      {Isotopes in Environmental and Health Studies},
  Number =       2,
  Pages =        {87--93},
  Title =        {Stability of iodine content in iodized salt},
  Volume =       38,
  Year =         2002,
  Bdsk-Url-1 =   {dx.doi.org/10.1080/10256010208033316}
}

@article{wang2014trends,
  Author =       {Wang, Dong D. and Leung, Cindy W. and Li, Yanping and
                  Ding, Eric L. and Chiuve, Stephanie E. and Hu, Frank B.
                  and Willett, Walter C.},
  Journal =      {JAMA Internal Medicine},
  Number =       10,
  Pages =        {1587--95},
  Timestamp =    {2015.02.27},
  Title =        {Trends in dietary quality among adults in the
                  {U}nited {S}tates: 1999 through 2010},
  Volume =       174,
  Year =         2014
}



\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite{wang2014trends,morris2008effective,biberanak2002,usami2012some,benoist2003,benoist2008}

\printbibliography

\printindex

\end{document}
```

I compile this using:

xelatex -interaction nonstopmode mwebib
biber mwebib
xelatex -interaction nonstopmode mwebib
xindy -M texindy -M page-ranges -L Turkish -C utf8 mwebib.idx
xelatex -interaction nonstopmode mwebib
xelatex -interaction nonstopmode mwebib

[image: Bibliography]

[image: Index]

Comment: This question consists of two parts - the policy on this site is to ask one question per question. The second is clearly a duplicate of your [Sorting author index made using biblatex, removing letter group headings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/264072/35864). While the first issue is addressed in many questions already, `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}` should be enough.

Comment: If you are OK with the answer to the first part, I would like to close this question as a duplicate of your other question.

Comment: \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} changes all names to LastName, FirstName format. This is not what I want. I want first author as Lastname, Firstname, and subsequent authors as Firstname Lastname, and I want the entries sorted using the same, and not Lastname, Firstname.

Comment: Aha. I suggest you ask a new question then. But this time please leave out the index thingy (it has nothing to do with this). What you want seems very very odd to me though, I might add. But maybe someone can help.