# Using glossaries package with Texmaker (running PDFLaTex)

Tags: pdftex, texmaker, glossaries

Currently I am using the `acronym` package to generate a glossary of acronyms, but I would like to also have a glossary of mathematical symbols. Therefore, I am looking to move to the `glossaries` package. I am having issues (detailed below) that the glossary section is not generated and so would like to know what is the simplest way to do this?

Below is a simple WORKING use case with `acronym`, from which I can generate a pdf, on mac os X, in texmaker (4.4.1) running the quick build option;

```
PdfLaTex + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTex(x2) + View Pdf
```

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,bibencoding=ascii]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{example_bib.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Body}

Try printing \ac{aa} and citing something.\cite{a_reference}

\section{Acronyms} 
\begin{acronym}[AAAAAAA]
\acro{aa}[AA]{An Acronym}
\end{acronym}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

example_bib.bib:

```
  @ARTICLE{a_reference,
  author = {A, Name},
  title = {A Title},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {1--2},
  abstract = {an abstarct},
  date = {2013-06},
  doi = {10.1016/j.commatsci.2013.03.013},
  issn = {0927-0256},
  journaltitle = {Computational Materials Science},
  keywords = {Keyword},
  shortjournal = {Computational Materials Science},
  url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com},
  urldate = {2015-10-28}}
```

If I try adapting the main.tex file to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,bibencoding=ascii]{biblatex}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{aa}{AA}{An Acronym} 

\addbibresource{example_bib.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Body}

Try printing \gls{aa} and citing something.\cite{a_reference}

\printacronyms

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

It runs, but there is NO glossary section output to the pdf! (the acronym is inserted in the body text)

This is also the case if I try using glossary terms:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,bibencoding=ascii]{biblatex}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{aa}{name=aa,description={A description of AA}}

\addbibresource{example_bib.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Body}

Try printing \gls{aa} and citing something.\cite{a_reference}

\printglossaries

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I have looked at a number of questions on here related to this issue, but none seem to provide an adequate answer.

Comment: You have the wrong type of brackets in `\newacronym{aa}[AA]{An Acronym}` They should all be curly brackets `{}` not square `[]`. So it should be `\newacronym{aa}{AA}{An Acronym} `

Comment: Thanks Nicola! What a schoolboy error lol. I still have the issue that the glossary section doesn't show up on the pdf though?

Comment: I have edited the question to focus on this problem

Comment: You need to run `makeglossaries` after `pdflatex`. You mentioned your build option is `PdfLaTex + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTex(x2) + View Pdf`. I don't use TeXMaker, but there needs to be a MakeGlossaries in there (either before or after Bib(la)tex). Alternatively, add the package option `automake`: \usepackage[automake]{glossaries}

Comment: Yes `automake` did the trick, thank you very much! This seems an easier option than messing with the build? Also, is there any other top tips you could give me for using `glossaries` that might not come up in the basic howto's?

Comment: If things go wrong, try [makeglossariesgui](http://ctan.org/pkg/makeglossariesgui), which is a diagnostic tool for the `glossaries` package. There are some examples of different styles in my [gallery](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/). Have you seen the [glossaries article on the LaTeX Community site](http://www.latex-community.org/know-how/latex/55-latex-general/263-glossaries-nomenclature-lists-of-symbols-and-acronyms)?

Comment: I've just converted my actual report to use `glossaries` and it all appears to be working great. No I hadn't seen them articles, so I will check them out. Thanks again Nicola

Comment: That's okay. I've posted an answer for completeness.

Comment: Sorry, I have one more quick related question; how can I have a 'group' variable show up in the glossary? So for example I have $V_i^a$, $V_i^b$, ...etc in the text, but in the glossary I just want to explain that $V_i^x$ is <definition of $V_i$> for some species x

Comment: Actually I should have just put a few seconds thought in before posting that! I guess I just have \newglossaryentry{alpha}{name={{}$\alpha^x$},text={{}\alpha},sort={alpha},
   description={...}}, then $\gls{alpha}^a$ in the text

Comment: Yes, that's right. If you don't set the `sort` key it defaults to the value of the `name`. From `makeindex`'s point of view characters like `{`, `}`, `$` and \ are just symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and easy method is to just add the `automake` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[acronym,automake]{glossaries}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,bibencoding=ascii]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{example_bib.bib}
@ARTICLE{a_reference,
  author = {A, Name},
  title = {A Title},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {1--2},
  abstract = {an abstarct},
  date = {2013-06},
  doi = {10.1016/j.commatsci.2013.03.013},
  issn = {0927-0256},
  journaltitle = {Computational Materials Science},
  keywords = {Keyword},
  shortjournal = {Computational Materials Science},
  url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com},
  urldate = {2015-10-28}}
\end{filecontents*}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{aa}{AA}{An Acronym} 

\addbibresource{example_bib.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Body}

Try printing \gls{aa} and citing something.\cite{a_reference}

\printacronyms

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This requires two `pdflatex` invocations, but you've got that already with your `PdfLaTex + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTex(x2) + View Pdf` build. This method makes use of TeX's shell escape mechanism. This is commonly set to restricted mode, which only allows trusted applications to run. Luckily, `makeindex` is a trusted application.

The `makeglossaries` Perl script supplied with the `glossaries` package runs `makeindex` (or `xindy`), but it also provides some diagnostic information. (Some of `xindy`'s messages are a bit cryptic.) [egreg's answer to another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61102) shows how to integrate `makeglossaries` with texmaker.

Personally, I prefer to use `arara`. With this method I just need to put some special comments in my source code:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,bibencoding=ascii]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{example_bib.bib}
@ARTICLE{a_reference,
  author = {A, Name},
  title = {A Title},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {1--2},
  abstract = {an abstarct},
  date = {2013-06},
  doi = {10.1016/j.commatsci.2013.03.013},
  issn = {0927-0256},
  journaltitle = {Computational Materials Science},
  keywords = {Keyword},
  shortjournal = {Computational Materials Science},
  url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com},
  urldate = {2015-10-28}}
\end{filecontents*}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{aa}{AA}{An Acronym} 

\addbibresource{example_bib.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Body}

Try printing \gls{aa} and citing something.\cite{a_reference}

\printacronyms

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

(There's [a question on integrating texmaker with arara](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/integration-of-arara-in-texmaker).)

You asked for some top tips in the comments. Here are the ones that I can think of off the top of my head:

- Define your entries (`\newglossaryentry`, `\newacronym` etc) in the preamble or put them in a separate file and load them in the preamble using `\input` or `\loadglsentries`.
- Avoid using special characters in the entry labels. This includes extended Latin or non-Latin characters, unless you're using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.
- Avoid using commands like `\gls` in section/chapter/captions etc. If you really need them, use the commands like `\glsfmttext{label}`, `\glsfmtshort{label}` or `\glsfmtlong{label}` provided by the [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) package.
- If your terms contain commands or special characters, provide the `sort` key. For example:

  ```
  \newglossaryentry{alpha}{name={$\alpha$},text={\alpha},sort={alpha},
     description={...}}
  \newacronym[sort={chi2}]{chisq}{$\chi^2$}{$\chi^2$-squared}
  ```
- If you want to use commands like `\Gls` that convert the first letter to upper case, be careful of the restrictions imposed by `\makefirstuc` (provided by [`mfirstuc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mfirstuc)). So the above examples should really be:

  ```
  \newglossaryentry{alpha}{name={{}$\alpha$},text={{}\alpha},sort={alpha},
     description={...}}
  \newacronym[sort={chi2}]{chisq}{{}$\chi^2$}{{}$\chi^2$-squared}
  ```

  (These types of entry shouldn't have any case-changing applied even if they do occur at the start of a sentence. The empty brace at the start of the value discards the attempt to change case, which would otherwise cause problems.)
- If things go wrong, for example, your glossary doesn't appear or has entries missing, try the [`makeglossariesgui`](http://ctan.org/pkg/makeglossariesgui) application to see if it can detect the problem.

Related resources:

- [glossaries FAQ](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries)
- [glossaries gallery](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/#glossaries)
- [Glossaries, Nomenclature, Lists of Symbols and Acronyms](http://www.latex-community.org/know-how/latex/55-latex-general/263-glossaries-nomenclature-lists-of-symbols-and-acronyms)