# Printing list of acronyms on the table of content

Tags: xetex, acronyms

I am writing a thesis and I would like to produce Acronyms list and glossary in the table of content. This my latex here

```
\documentclass[8pt]{report}
%\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
        name=latex,
        description={Is a mark up language specially suited for 
scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
        name=mathematics,
        description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\newglossaryentry{formula}
{
        name=formula,
        description={A mathematical expression}
}

\newacronym{abcp}{ABCP}{Asset Backed Commercial Paper}
\newacronym{aig}{AIG}{American International Group}
\newacronym{bcbs}{BCBS}{Basel Committee on Banking Supervision}
\newacronym{cdo}{CDO}{Collateral Debit Obligation}
\newacronym{cds}{CDS}{Credit Default Swap}
\newacronym{cmbs}{CMBS}{Commercial Mortgage-Backed Securities}
\newacronym{cva}{CVA}{Credit Valuation Default}
\newacronym{ead}{EaD}{Exposure at Default}
\newacronym{fsb}{FSB}{Financial Stability Board}
\newacronym{gfc}{GFC}{Global Financial Crisis}
\newacronym{mbs}{MBS}{Mortgage-Backed Securities}
\newacronym{otc}{OTC}{Over-The-Counter}
\newacronym{pfe}{PFE}{Potential Future Exposure}
\newacronym{rc}{RC}{Replacement Cost}
\newacronym{rmbs}{RMBS}{Residential Mortgage-Backed Securities}
\newacronym{saccr}{SA-CCR}{Standard Approach for Counterparty Credit Risk}
\newacronym{us}{US}{United States

}
\begin{document} 
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\printacronyms
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}\label{chap1}
\end{document}
```

How do I produce the list acronyms, I tried `\printacronyms` but they are still not showing

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Please make your document example shorter. In preamble load only needed packages and put definition needed for your problem.

Comment: Okay, Thanks, done

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer, I'll explain it later on

```
\documentclass[8pt]{report}
%\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
        name=latex,
        description={Is a mark up language specially suited for 
scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
        name=mathematics,
        description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\newglossaryentry{formula}
{
        name=formula,
        description={A mathematical expression}
}

\newacronym{abcp}{ABCP}{Asset Backed Commercial Paper}
\newacronym{aig}{AIG}{American International Group}
\newacronym{bcbs}{BCBS}{Basel Committee on Banking Supervision}
\newacronym{cdo}{CDO}{Collateral Debit Obligation}
\newacronym{cds}{CDS}{Credit Default Swap}
\newacronym{cmbs}{CMBS}{Commercial Mortgage-Backed Securities}
\newacronym{cva}{CVA}{Credit Valuation Default}
\newacronym{ead}{EaD}{Exposure at Default}
\newacronym{fsb}{FSB}{Financial Stability Board}
\newacronym{gfc}{GFC}{Global Financial Crisis}
\newacronym{mbs}{MBS}{Mortgage-Backed Securities}
\newacronym{otc}{OTC}{Over-The-Counter}
\newacronym{pfe}{PFE}{Potential Future Exposure}
\newacronym{rc}{RC}{Replacement Cost}
\newacronym{rmbs}{RMBS}{Residential Mortgage-Backed Securities}
\newacronym{saccr}{SA-CCR}{Standard Approach for Counterparty Credit Risk}
\newacronym{us}{US}{United States}



\begin{document} 
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\printacronyms
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\glsaddall     %%% ADDITION 1
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=super,nonumberlist]    %%% ADDITION 2
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}\label{chap1}
\end{document}
```

Please note that you need to compile once with pdfLaTeX, then you should `makeglossaries` and then recompile.
The command `\glsaddall` is used so to make the acronyms appear even if they are not called in the main text. If you don't want this behavior, just delete that line.

In order to create a "makeglossaries" command you have first to be sure you have Perl installed on your system. If that is the case, the solution is straightforward, otherwise a bit of tuning is needed.

If you have Perl (or you would like to download it from here, for example: https://strawberryperl.com/), just go into your Tex software (scripting, composition, etc... for example). I have TexWorks and I needed to create a new process as follows

[image]

The compilation order is then 1. pdfLaTex, 2. makeglossaries, 3. pdfLaTeX.

If you do not have Perl I suggest you to search on StackExchange how to do it (I found it once but it seems I cannot right now)... use keywords as "acronyms", "glossaries", "not appearing", "Perl".

Hope you fix it, I struggled with it for few days!!!

Comment: I tried, I installed Perl also but not working. I am working with Texmaker,  and created a makeglossaries command then 1. compile with PDFLATEX (FILENAME.TEX)   2. make

Comment: Please have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314057/using-glossaries-package-with-texmaker-running-pdflatex specifically for TexMaker
Specifically also here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110095/list-of-acronyms-is-not-displayed

You need to have certain specification for makeglossaries depending on the software you're using and the operating system

Comment: For ACRONYM it worked pretty well but struggling with glossary to print.

Comment: Just add the \printglossary[style=super,nonumberlist] command with no acronym type

Comment: How can add list of symbols?