# glossaries not showing

Tags: glossaries, texmaker

Any idea why my glossaries are not showing?

```
%--- Long usepackage list, it got included to check for possible conflicts ----
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}            
\usepackage{rotating}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage[scriptsize]{caption}
\usepackage[toc,section=chapter,acronym,automake]{glossaries}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{romannum}

\makeglossaries
\glstoctrue
\loadglsentries{glossario}

\begin{document} 
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
%---- List of chapters to include ----
\printglossaries
% ---- Bibliography ----
\appendix
% ---- Appendices includes ----
\end{document}
```

They were showing just fine, I worked on the document for a few days and I must have not realized they weren't showing anymore. The \gls{} and \acr{} are working but no glossary page get printed.
I'm using Texmaker, my settings are:

- Quick compile: PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX (x2) + Display Pdf
- Commands: PdfLaTeX: LateX_folder\miktex\bin\pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

I tried every suggestion I could find, now I'm afraid some package is conflicting with the glossaries.

Comment: Your quick compile list is missing the makeglossaries call. (Not sure why it's showing as part of the pdflatex command, but I'm not familiar with texmaker.)

Comment: Related: [Using Texmaker with glossaries on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61099)

Comment: The makeglossaries call is concatenated in the PdfLaTeX command

Comment: You also have `automake` which should run `makeindex` from the shell escape (in which case the `makeglossaries` call is redundant). Check if there's a `.glg` or `.alg` file present, and if so check them for errors. It's better if you [trim down](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/hackingdown.html) your MWE so that it doesn't have all the included files.

Comment: I trimmed down my MWE and remove the makeglossaries command, any guess why my glossaries are not showing?

Comment: Your MWE doesn't help to diagnose the problem because it can't be used by any of us to reproduce the problem: the contents of `glossario.tex` are missing, there are no instances of commands like `\gls` in the code you've provided. There could be any number of things that are hidden in your included files that might be causing a problem. See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 2):

First check your document build is correct with a simple document:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[toc,acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}
\newacronym{ex}{ex}{example}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Sample Chapter}
\gls{sample}, \gls{ex}.

\printglossaries

\appendix
\chapter{Sample Appendix}

\gls{sample}, \gls{ex}.
\end{document}
```

If the file is called `myDoc.tex` then the document build is:

```
pdflatex myDoc
makeglossaries myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

- The first LaTeX call doesn't display the glossaries but writes the files needed to generate them.
- The `makeglossaries` call uses the `makeglossaries` Perl script which runs `makeindex` or `xindy` on the appropriate files. In this case it runs `makeindex` twice because there are two glossaries (the default `main` glossary, which is always created unless `nomain` is used, and the `acronym` glossary, which is created by the `acronym` package option).
- The second LaTeX call reads the files created by `makeindex` which contain the code to typeset the glossaries.
- The third LaTeX call ensures that the table of contents is up to date.

You have some unnecessary code in your example:

```
\glstoctrue
```

This is automatically implemented by the `toc` package option. The glossaries don't show in the table of contents until the third LaTeX call.

```
section=chapter
```

This isn't needed as it's the default with any class file that defines `\chapter` (which is the case with `report`).

```
automake
```

This option tells the `glossaries` package to use TeX's shell escape to run `makeindex` or `xindy`. TeX can be run with the shell escape completely disabled (in which case `automake` won't work), with the shell escape in restricted mode (`automake` will only work for trusted applications, so it works for `makeindex` but not for `xindy`) or with the shell escape fully enabled (a security risk, but allows `automake` to work with `xindy`).

If you have a build process that runs `makeglossaries` (or `makeglossaries-lite`, or explicitly `makeindex`/`xindy`) then you don't need `automake`.

It's best to load `glossaries` last (unless another required package indicates otherwise). It's one of the few exceptions to the general rule that `hyperref` should be loaded last. Your example doesn't use `hyperref` so it may not be so much of a problem if other packages are loaded after `glossaries`.

```
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
```

Unrelated to `glossaries`, but you've informed `graphicx` that you're using the DVI format but you've stated that your build process uses pdfLaTeX. With modern TeX distributions you shouldn't need to tell packages which LaTeX format you're using but, where you do, it should actually match whereas this conflicts.

If the above example works fine for you, then your build process is working correctly, which means the problem is somewhere in the document code. The next step is to add the other packages to see if they cause a conflict:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[scriptsize]{caption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{romannum}

\usepackage[toc,acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}
\newacronym{ex}{ex}{example}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Sample Chapter}
\gls{sample}, \gls{ex}.

\printglossaries

\appendix
\chapter{Sample Appendix}

\gls{sample}, \gls{ex}.
\end{document}
```

This document compiles fine for me. If it doesn't work for you then add

```
\listfiles
```

at the start which will show the version numbers of all the loaded packages at the end of the `.log` file. Compare these with the latest version on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/). It's possible that you might have a old version that's causing a problem.

If this second example works fine for you, then it's possible there's a problem with one or more of the entry definitions in your `glossario.tex` file. So the next step is to check the transcript files created by `makeindex`. These have the extensions `.glg` (for the `main` glossary) and `.alg` (for the `acronym` glossary). Are there any error messages in these files?

My example document was called `test.tex`, so the first transcript file is `test.glg` and contains:

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2017] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file ./test.ist.............................done (29 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
Scanning input file test.glo....done (2 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Sorting entries....done (2 comparisons).
Generating output file test.gls....done (7 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in test.gls.
Transcript written in test.glg.
```

The second transcript file is `test.alg` and contains:

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2017] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file ./test.ist.............................done (29 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
Scanning input file test.glo....done (2 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Sorting entries....done (2 comparisons).
Generating output file test.gls....done (7 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in test.gls.
Transcript written in test.glg.
```

The key line in both case is the one that contains `(2 entries accepted, 0 rejected)`. If any entries have been rejected, then you have a problem with your `glossario.tex` file, in which case change the above example document so that the `\newglossaryentry` and `\newacronym` definitions are replaced with one of the `\newglossaryentry` and `\newacronym` definitions from your `glossario.tex` file, and replace the corresponding `\gls{sample}` and `\gls{ex}`.

Here are some possible things that might be wrong (but this is just guesswork without knowing what's actually in that file):

- One or more of the labels may contain special characters or other content that can't be expanded to a simple label. This includes UTF-8 characters when you have `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (but not a problem with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX).
- Something in the `sort` field (which is obtained from `name` if omitted) contains code that's interfering with the mechanism used to escape `makeindex`'s special characters.

The first is the most common problem of the two.

If the example document still works with this modification, try each term defined in `glossario.tex` until you find one that fails. If none of them fail, then the problem may lie in the way you are referencing the terms. Since you haven't provided an example of how you're using `\gls` (or similar commands), this is again just guesswork. You have to [hack down](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/hackingdown.html) to pinpoint the problem.

Possible problems:

- You haven't used `\gls` (or similar commands) anywhere in your document. (The transcript file will show `0 entries accepted, 0 rejected`.)
- `\gls` (or similar) has been used in some context that's interfering with the indexing.

The first is the most commonly encountered cause.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently moving the appendices before the glossaries fixed the problem, the glossaries are printed correctly. LaTeX is powerful and I barely scratched the surface of the possibilites that it offers but sometimes it's just stupid.

Comment: Then there's something wrong with your code that you haven't told us about. It shouldn't make any difference where the glossaries are relative to the appendices (given your document preamble).

Comment: I don't know what to say, the only parts I didn't post are the chapters, just plain latex. I didn't hide anything.