# List of abbreviations when abbreviations are in a separate folder

Tags: texmaker, acronyms, nomenclature

I have looked a several sources to answer this question, including [textblog](https://texblog.org/2014/01/15/glossary-and-list-of-acronyms-with-latex/), [latex.org](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=28984) and [sharelatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Glossaries#Acronyms). I have copied the code and although I do not get any errors I do not get a list of abbreviations as required or even the heading **Abbreviations** (or Glossaries or any other heading). My abbreviations are in a separate folder so I do not know if this makes a difference. Also, I am using Texmaker.

I have a 'main' folder that has all the preamble code and brings all the other folders/chapters together using the 'include' command, e.g.:

```
\include{Frontmatter/title}
\newpage

\include{Frontmatter/abstract}


\include{Frontmatter/acknowledgements}

\include{Frontmatter/abbreviations}


\include{Frontmatter/declaration}


\tableofcontents
\newpage

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}\textit{List of figures}}
\newpage

\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}\textit{List of tables}}
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{Chapters/ch1/ch1}

\include{Chapters/ch2/ch2}
etc.
```

I am still relatively new to Latex so simple examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should start with a simple example. What you have shown us, is absolutely worthless, we cannot test it, cannot compile it, cannot give any advice. From the five or so packages that do what you want, which one are you using? Have you run the helper program that creates the needed information? Is a helper program even needed?

Comment: You are including the *List of*s to the contents with the wrong page number.

Comment: Well, I have copied the code directly from the links I posted and I do not get anything. I even saved a new file and used only the answers provided in those links and still nothing. So I thought it may have something to do with having separate folders or perhaps Texmaker.

Comment: If your definitions are in the file that's input with `\include`, then there are two problems: [Why shouldn't I use \include to include my glossary definitions?](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries#include) and [Drawbacks With Defining Entries in the Document Environment](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot That explains it. Thanks for the links. I wonder if there is an easy way to do it by hand then. I suppose I can simply list the items, but is there a way that ensures it automatically puts item in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there may be multiple issues. I've already mentioned a couple in the comments, but I think there may be more:

- You have the abbreviation definitions within the `document` environment. [Drawbacks with Defining Entries in the Document Environment](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs)
- The file containing the abbreviation definitions has been input with `\include` rather than `\input`. [Why shouldn't I use \include to include my glossary definitions?](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries#include)
- It's not possible to tell from your code fragments, but you may have not used any of the commands needed to index the abbreviations. Without these, the list of abbreviations will be empty.
- You may have omitted the step required to process the indexing from the previous point.

Suppose you have a file called `abbreviations.tex` that contains:

```
\newacronym{xml}{XML}{extensible markup language}
\newacronym{svg}{SVG}{scalable vector graphics}
\newacronym{html}{HTML}{hypertext markup language}
```

Then this should be input in the *preamble* using either `\input` or `\loadglsentries`. Within the document you need to use commands like [`\gls`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:gls-like), which both deals with first/subsequent use formatting and the indexing.

Here's a complete document:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries{abbreviations}

\title{Sample Document}
\author{Ann Author}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\printglossary[title={Abbreviations}]

\mainmatter

\include{introduction}

\end{document}
```

where `introduction.tex` contains:

```
\chapter{Introduction}

Something about \gls{html}. Something else about \gls{html}.
```

If the main file is called `myDoc.tex` then the build process is:

```
pdflatex myDoc
makeglossaries myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

Alternatively (if you don't have Perl installed):

```
pdflatex myDoc
makeglossaries-lite myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

(Depending on your setup, you may need to use `makeglossaries-lite.lua` instead of `makeglossaries-lite`.)

If you are using a text editor where you just click a button to run LaTeX, then you need to find a way to add `makeglossaries` (or `makeglossaries-lite`) as a recognised tool. This depends on the editor. Since you've used the `texmaker` tag, I'm guessing that's what you're using so try [Using Texmaker with glossaries on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61099).

The list of abbreviations will only be present after the associated file has been created (during the `makeglossaries`/`makeglossaries-lite` step.)

Another option is to use the `automake` package option, which will try to generate the associated file during the LaTeX run using TeX's shell escape. Since there are security concerns with TeX being able to execute other applications, this action may be prohibited depending on your TeX setup.

For example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[automake]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries{abbreviations}

\title{Sample Document}
\author{Ann Author}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\printglossary[title={Abbreviations}]

\mainmatter

\include{introduction}

\end{document}
```

The document build is now:

```
pdflatex myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

The list of abbreviations only includes the term that has been referenced in the document with `\gls`:

[image: Abbreviations HTML hypertext markup language. 1]

(The 1 refers to the page number where `\gls{html}` was used. If you don't want it, use the `nonumberlist` package option.)

The `xml` and `svg` terms aren't listed because they haven't been referenced. Here's a modified version of `introduction.tex`:

```
\chapter{Introduction}

Something about \gls{html}.  Something else about \gls{html}.
Something about \gls{xml}.
```

Rebuild the document, and now XML is listed:

[image: Abbreviations HTML hypertext markup language. 1 XML extensible markup language. 1]

The SVG term still isn't listed.

This is the most common method of using the `glossaries` package. A similar method is to add the `xindy` package option. The build process is much the same but now `makeglossaries` will try to run [`xindy`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xindy) instead of [`makeindex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/makeindex).

There is another method that doesn't use any external tool as it uses TeX to sort and collate, but it's the [least efficient method and can break in some instances](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-performance.shtml). Here's the modified document:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries % <--- use TeX to sort and collate

\loadglsentries{abbreviations}

\title{Sample Document}
\author{Ann Author}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\printnoidxglossary[title={Abbreviations}]% <--- use TeX to sort and collate

\mainmatter

\include{introduction}

\end{document}
```

The [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) extension package provides a manual method, where no sorting or collating takes place. Instead all defined terms will be listed in order of definition, even if they haven't been used in the document. Here's the modified document:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[sort=none]{glossaries-extra}

% set the abbreviation style before abbreviations are defined:
\setabbreviationstyle % requires glossaries-extra.sty
 [acronym]% governs \newacronym (unless category key is set)
 {long-short}% style name

\loadglsentries{abbreviations}

\title{Sample Document}
\author{Ann Author}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\printunsrtglossary[title={Abbreviations}]% <--- no sorting or collating

\mainmatter

\include{introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image: Abbreviations XML extensible markup language SVG scalable vector graphics HTML hypertext markup language]

All entries are now listed but they are in the order of definition and there's no number list. The full stop following the description that was automatically added with the base `glossaries` example is missing. You can add it back with the package option `postdot` or `postpunc=dot`.

With `glossaries-extra`, you can use `\newabbreviation` instead of `\newacronym`. For example:

```
\newabbreviation{xml}{XML}{extensible markup language}
\newabbreviation{svg}{SVG}{scalable vector graphics}
\newabbreviation{html}{HTML}{hypertext markup language}
```

The `[acronym]` optional argument should now be omitted from `\setabbreviationstyle`:

```
% set the abbreviation style before abbreviations are defined:
\setabbreviationstyle % requires glossaries-extra.sty
 {long-short}% style name
```

In fact, the `long-short` style is the default for `\newabbreviation`, so you can omit this. I've included it below to highlight where the command needs to go if a different style is required.

The final method is to use a `.bib` format instead. If you have a large number of terms you may find this more convenient as you can manage the file in a bibliographic management system, such as [JabRef](https://ctan.org/pkg/jabref).

The abbreviations are now defined in a file called `abbreviations.bib` (instead of `abbreviations.tex`):

```
% Encoding: UTF-8
@abbreviation{xml,
  short = {XML},
  long = {extensible markup language}
}

@abbreviation{svg,
  short = {SVG},
  long = {scalable vector graphics}
}

@abbreviation{html,
  short = {HTML},
  long = {hypertext markup language}
}
```

The document is now:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[record]% using bib2gls
 {glossaries-extra}

% set the abbreviation style before abbreviations are defined:
\setabbreviationstyle % requires glossaries-extra.sty
 {long-short}% style name

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
 src={abbreviations}% definitions provided in abbreviations.bib
]

\title{Sample Document}
\author{Ann Author}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\printunsrtglossary[title={Abbreviations}]% <--- using bib2gls

\mainmatter

\include{introduction}

\end{document}
```

and the build process is:

```
pdflatex myDoc
bib2gls myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

Again, you need to add `bib2gls` as a recognised tool to your text editor. Just follow the same steps as for `makeglossaries`, but replace `makeglossaries` with `bib2gls`.

---

- For all methods except `sort=none`, you must index the terms that need to appear in the list of abbreviations using commands like `\gls`. Terms that aren't indexed won't appear in the list.
- For all methods except the first (`\makeglossaries` with just the base `glossaries` package), you can't define terms in the `document` environment. With the first method you can, but things can go wrong.
- Only use `\input` or `\loadglsentries` not `\include` (except for the `bib2gls` method where you need to use `\GlsXtrLoadResources`).

Since there are multiple ways of using the `glossaries` and `glossaries-extra` packages, if you have a problem then you need to provide a short but complete example document (like the ones here) and state how you are building the document.