# \printnoidxglossaries vs \printglossaries

Tags: glossaries, texmaker

I'm using texmaker on windows and have serious trouble to use glossaries properly using \printglossaries. 
After installing and reinstalling activeperl nothing has changed. 
whenever I try to output the glossaries nothing shows up.

So I'm using \printnoidxglossaries. Is that a disadvantage or can anyone tell me what the possible reason for the dysfunction of \printglossaries could be. 
My main goal is to create multiple glossaries to show the symbols im using in my thesis and the acronyms. Right now I used some replacement solution (table) to solve the problem.

I searched high and low to find a proper explanation how to set something like that up, but to no avail. any help is hughely appreciated!!!

merci in advance

A

Sample for the glossary i wan to create (now as table)

[image]

And here the code where i Have tried to create multiple glossaries.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,booktabs,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}


\newglossary[ch1]{formel}{ch2}{ch3}{Formelverzeichnis}

\makenoidxglossaries
\setacronymstyle{long-short}

\newglossarystyle{formel_altlong4colheader}{%
    \setglossarystyle{altlong4colheader}%
% 



                      %------Acronym---------
\renewcommand*{\acronymname}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\newacronym[shortplural={BLKs},longplural={Belastungskollektive}]{BLK}{BLK}{Belastungskollektiv}
\newacronym{DL}{DL}{Dauerlauf}
\newacronym[shortplural={Fzg-DL},longplural={Fahrzeugdauerläufen}]{Fzg-DL}{Fzg-DL}{Fahrzeug
Dauerlauf}

                      %-----Formel---
\newglossaryentry{re}
{%
    name={$R_e$},
    description={Streckgrenze},
    symbol={Pa},
    sort=streckgrenze,
    type=formel
}
\newglossaryentry{rm}
{%
    name={$R_m$},
    description={Zugfestigkeit},
    symbol={Pa},
    sort=Zugfestigkeit,
    type=formel
}



\begin{document}

\printnoidxglossary[type=acronym]
\printnoidxglossary[type=formel,style=formel_altlong4colheader]

\setglossarystyle{formel_altlong4colheader}
\newpage
\gls{BLK}
\gls{DL}
\gls{Fzg-DL}
\gls{re}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. Could you add some working code, called minimal working example(MWE), which starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`

Comment: See [the `glossaries` performance page](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-performance.shtml) for a comparison, but you don't need Perl. You can use the `makeglossaries-lite` Lua script instead. See also [What can interfere with glossaries to prevent printing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309233)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick reply. @Nicola: can I simply replace the \makeglossaries command through the \makeglossaries-lite command? Without installing anything else? I tried but to no avail. I would truly love if someone could either show here or point me to any paper etc. showing how to generate a glossary/ nomenclatur in table style? merci

Comment: `makeglossaries` and `makeglossaries-lite` are scripts not commands. (It's a bit confusing since there's also a command called `\makeglossaries` that you use in the document.)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are actually five methods of generating glossary lists (summarised in section [1.1 Indexing Options](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:indexingoptions) of the `glossaries` user manual). The first uses `\printnoidxglossaries`, the second two use `\printglossaries` and the last two (which require [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra)) use `\printunsrtglossaries`. [Table 1.1: Glossary Options: Pros and Cons](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#tab:options) summarizes the advantages and disadvantages of each method.

Using a slightly trimmed version of your MWE, here are all the methods:

### 1.`\printnoidxglossaries`

This method doesn't require any external tools, but it's designed for ASCII sort values and it can [significantly slow the document build](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-performance.shtml). If the sort value contains fragile commands, you need to use the `sanitizesort` setting.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}

\newglossary[ch1]{formel}{ch2}{ch3}{Formelverzeichnis}

\makenoidxglossaries
\setacronymstyle{long-short}

                      %------Acronym---------
\renewcommand*{\acronymname}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\newacronym[shortplural={BLKs},longplural={Belastungskollektive}]{BLK}{BLK}{Belastungskollektiv}
\newacronym{DL}{DL}{Dauerlauf}
\newacronym[shortplural={Fzg-DL},longplural={Fahrzeugdauerläufen}]{Fzg-DL}{Fzg-DL}{Fahrzeug
Dauerlauf}

                      %-----Formel---
\newglossaryentry{re}
{%
    name={$R_e$},
    description={Streckgrenze},
    symbol={Pa},
    sort=streckgrenze,
    type=formel
}
\newglossaryentry{rm}
{%
    name={$R_m$},
    description={Zugfestigkeit},
    symbol={Pa},
    sort=Zugfestigkeit,
    type=formel
}

\begin{document}

\printnoidxglossary[type=acronym]
\printnoidxglossary[type=formel,style=altlong4colheader]

\newpage
\gls{BLK}
\gls{DL}
\gls{Fzg-DL}
\gls{re}

\end{document}
```

If the document is called `myDoc.tex`, then the complete document build process requires:

```
pdflatex myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

UTF-8 characters, such as ü and ä, won't be correctly sorted.

Page 1:

[image: Akronyme BLK Belastungskollektiv. 1 DL Dauerlauf. 1 Fzg-DL Fahrzeug Dauerlauf. 1]

Page 3:

[image: Formelverzeichnis Bezeichnung Beschreibung Symbol Seiten Re Streckgrenze Pa 1]

Since `rm` hasn't been referenced in the document (with, e.g., `\gls{rm}`) it doesn't appear in the list.

Symbols are often problematic with this method, but since you've used the `sort` key to assign an alphabetic value (`sort=streckgrenze`) this shouldn't cause a problem in this case.

This method also can't form ranges in the location (page) lists.

### 2. `makeindex` (`\printglossaries`)

This method uses the helper application `makeindex` to generate the sorted lists. The command `\makeglossaries` is needed to ensure that the appropriate files are created for `makeindex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}

\newglossary[ch1]{formel}{ch2}{ch3}{Formelverzeichnis}

\makeglossaries
\setacronymstyle{long-short}

                      %------Acronym---------
\renewcommand*{\acronymname}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\newacronym[shortplural={BLKs},longplural={Belastungskollektive}]{BLK}{BLK}{Belastungskollektiv}
\newacronym{DL}{DL}{Dauerlauf}
\newacronym[shortplural={Fzg-DL},longplural={Fahrzeugdauerläufen}]{Fzg-DL}{Fzg-DL}{Fahrzeug
Dauerlauf}

                      %-----Formel---
\newglossaryentry{re}
{%
    name={$R_e$},
    description={Streckgrenze},
    symbol={Pa},
    sort=streckgrenze,
    type=formel
}
\newglossaryentry{rm}
{%
    name={$R_m$},
    description={Zugfestigkeit},
    symbol={Pa},
    sort=Zugfestigkeit,
    type=formel
}    

\begin{document}

\printglossary[type=acronym]
\printglossary[type=formel,style=altlong4colheader]

\newpage
\gls{BLK}
\gls{DL}
\gls{Fzg-DL}
\gls{re}

\end{document}
```

If the document is called `myDoc.tex` then the complete document build process is:

```
pdflatex myDoc
makeindex -s myDoc.ist -t myDoc.alg -o myDoc.acr myDoc.acn
makeindex -s myDoc.ist -t myDoc.ch1 -o myDoc.ch2 myDoc.ch3
pdflatex myDoc
```

Note that there must be a separate `makeindex` call for each glossary. Since this document has two lists, there must be two `makeindex` calls. This is quite cumbersome, so the `glossaries` package provides two scripts to run `makeindex` the required number of times with the required settings. In both cases the script reads the `.aux` file to find out what systems calls need to be made.

The first script is the `makeglossaries` Perl script, which needs Perl installed. The build process is now simplified to:

```
pdflatex myDoc
makeglossaries myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

The second script is the `makeglossaries-lite` Lua script. This is on CTAN as [`makeglossaries-lite.lua`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/makeglossaries-lite.lua) but the TeX distributions may change the extension. (For example, TeX Live on Linux creates a symbolic link called `makeglossaries-lite` without the extensions.) So if there's no extension, the build process is:

```
pdflatex myDoc
makeglossaries-lite myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

but the `.lua` extension is retained you may need to do:

```
pdflatex myDoc
makeglossaries-lite.lua myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

I suspect the problem that you're having is integrating this step into TeXMaker. See [Using Texmaker with glossaries on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61099) for further help.

Another possibility is to use the `automake` package option. This will try to use TeX's shell escape to run `makeindex`:

```
\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts,automake]{glossaries}
```

The resulting document is the same as in the previous example. Again, this method isn't designed for UTF-8, as `makeindex` doesn't have UTF-8 support.

Since `makeindex` isn't aware of LaTeX commands, sort values that contain markup can result in odd ordering. For example, the sort value `\emph{word}` will be sorted according to the characters `\` `e` `m` `p` `h` `{` `w` `o` `r` `d` `}` which will put it in the symbols group (rather than in the more intuitive W letter group).

### 2. `xindy` (`\printglossaries`)

This method is very similar to the `makeindex` method, from the document code point of view, but it requires the `xindy` package option:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts,xindy]{glossaries}

\newglossary[ch1]{formel}{ch2}{ch3}{Formelverzeichnis}

\makeglossaries
\setacronymstyle{long-short}

                      %------Acronym---------
\renewcommand*{\acronymname}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\newacronym[shortplural={BLKs},longplural={Belastungskollektive}]{BLK}{BLK}{Belastungskollektiv}
\newacronym{DL}{DL}{Dauerlauf}
\newacronym[shortplural={Fzg-DL},longplural={Fahrzeugdauerläufen}]{Fzg-DL}{Fzg-DL}{Fahrzeug
Dauerlauf}

                      %-----Formel---
\newglossaryentry{re}
{%
    name={$R_e$},
    description={Streckgrenze},
    symbol={Pa},
    sort=streckgrenze,
    type=formel
}
\newglossaryentry{rm}
{%
    name={$R_m$},
    description={Zugfestigkeit},
    symbol={Pa},
    sort=Zugfestigkeit,
    type=formel
}

\begin{document}

\printglossary[type=acronym]
\printglossary[type=formel,style=altlong4colheader]

\newpage
\gls{BLK}
\gls{DL}
\gls{Fzg-DL}
\gls{re}

\end{document}
```

In this case, `\makeglossaries` is still needed to create the associated files needed by `xindy` (an alternative to `makeindex`), but the `xindy` package option ensures that the information is written in `xindy`'s format. The build process is now:

```
pdflatex myDoc
xindy -L german -C din5007-utf8 -I xindy -M myDoc -t myDoc.ch1 -o myDoc.ch2 myDoc.ch3
xindy  -L german -C din5007-utf8 -I xindy -M myDoc -t myDoc.alg -o myDoc.acr myDoc.acn
pdflatex myDoc
```

Again, this is quite cumbersome, so you can use the `makeglossaries` or `makeglossaries-lite` scripts. In this case, `makeglossaries-lite` doesn't work so well as it's not as intelligent as `makeglossaries`, but since `xindy` is a Perl script, there's no advantage to using `makeglossaries-lite` in this case. So the best document build is:

```
pdflatex myDoc
makeglossaries myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

In other words, the document build process is effectively the same as for the previous example.

This method has the advantage over the previous two methods in that it supports UTF-8 and non-English languages, so it should correctly order German words.

The disadvantage with this method its lack of support for symbols. Xindy strips all LaTeX commands and braces from the sort value, which is usually desirable (for example, if you have a sort value of `\emph{word}` it's good that xindy treats this as just `word`), but it causes a problem when the entire sort value consists solely of commands. For example, `\ensuremath{\alpha}` devolves into an empty string, which xindy doesn't like. The other problem is that xindy merges entries with identical sort values, so if stripping commands causes the sort value of one entry to become identical to another, then the entries will be merged.

You've used the `sort` key in your symbols (such as `sort=streckgrenze`) so this isn't a problem.

### 4. `bib2gls` (`\printunsrtglossaries`)

This method requires the `glossaries-extra` extension package and the [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls) helper application (which requires Java). This uses a different approach to the other methods. All entries are defined in `.bib` files.

So you might have the file `abbreviations.bib` that contains:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@abbreviation{BLK,
  short = {BLK},
  long  = {Belastungskollektiv},
  longplural = {Belastungskollektive}
}

@abbreviation{DL,
  short = {DL},
  long = {Dauerlauf}
}

@abbreviation{Fzg-DL,
  short = {Fzg-DL},
  shortplural = {Fzg-DL},
  long = {Fahrzeug Dauerlauf},
  longplural = {Fahrzeugdauerläufen}
}
```

and `symbols.bib` that contains:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@symbol{re,
  name={$R_e$},
  description={Streckgrenze},
  symbol={Pa}
}

@symbol{rm,
  name={$R_m$},
  description={Zugfestigkeit},
  symbol={Pa}
}
```

The document code is much simpler now:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[abbreviations,shortcuts,record]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossary[ch1]{formel}{ch2}{ch3}{Formelverzeichnis}

\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
 src={abbreviations}% entries defined in abbreviations.bib
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
 src={symbols},% entries defined in abbreviations.bib
 type = formel, % put these entries in the 'formel' list
 sort-field=description % sort according to the 'description' field
]

\begin{document}

\printunsrtglossary[type=abbreviations,title=Abkürzungsverzeichnis]
\printunsrtglossary[type=formel,style=altlong4colheader]

\newpage
\gls{BLK}
\gls{DL}
\gls{Fzg-DL}
\gls{re}

\end{document}
```

The document build process is now:

```
pdflatex myDoc
bib2gls myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

So again you need to find a way to integrate a helper application into your build process. This method has the advantage over the first two in that it supports UTF-8 and non-English sorting. (The document language setting is picked up from the `.aux` file.) It also has the advantage over `xindy` in that `bib2gls` allows empty and identical sort values, but it also has a limited understanding of some basic kernel symbol commands. For example, it will convert `\ensuremath{\alpha}` into the mathematical Greek lower case alpha . As illustrated in the above (`sort-field=description`), you can also sort according to a different field, if that provides a more appropriate order.

### 5. `\printunsrtglossaries` (no sorting)

This final method doesn't do any sorting or indexing. All defined entries are listed, regardless of whether they've been used in the document. Entries are listed in order of definition:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[abbreviations,shortcuts,sort=none]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossary[ch1]{formel}{ch2}{ch3}{Formelverzeichnis}

\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}

\newacronym[shortplural={BLKs},longplural={Belastungskollektive}]{BLK}{BLK}{Belastungskollektiv}
\newacronym{DL}{DL}{Dauerlauf}
\newacronym[shortplural={Fzg-DL},longplural={Fahrzeugdauerläufen}]{Fzg-DL}{Fzg-DL}{Fahrzeug
Dauerlauf}

\newglossaryentry{re}
{%
    name={$R_e$},
    description={Streckgrenze},
    symbol={Pa},
    type=formel
}
\newglossaryentry{rm}
{%
    name={$R_m$},
    description={Zugfestigkeit},
    symbol={Pa},
    type=formel
}

\begin{document}

\printunsrtglossary[type=abbreviations,title=Abkürzungsverzeichnis]
\printunsrtglossary[type=formel,style=altlong4colheader]

\newpage
\gls{BLK}
\gls{DL}
\gls{Fzg-DL}
\gls{re}

\end{document}
```

The document build process is simply:

```
pdflatex myDoc
```

Page 1 now looks like:

[image: Abkürzungsverzeichnis BLK Belastungskollektiv DL Dauerlauf Fzg-DL Fahrzeug Dauerlauf]

Page 3 now looks like:

[image: Formelverzeichnis Bezeichnung Beschreibung Symbol Seiten Re Streckgrenze Pa Rm Zugfestigkeit Pa]

Note that there are no location (page) lists.

### Summary

- Options 1 and 5 are the simplest as they don't require any external tools.
- Options 2, 3 and 4 all require an external tool which needs to be incorporated into your build process. How you do this depends on your text editor.
- Option 2 doesn't require any additional software (`makeindex` is precompiled and available with all modern TeX distributions).
- Option 3 requires Perl.
- Option 4 requires Java.
- Options 3 and 4 work best for UTF-8 non-English sort values.

For help integrating the external tools into your document build, see [Incorporating makeglossaries or makeglossaries-lite or bib2gls into the document build](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/buildglossaries).

Comment: Wow Nicola, what a detailed answer. I truly thank you, although I need to digest it first all tomorrow and might get back to you if I dont get something. However. thanks a lot! A

Comment: Ah, one question directly: how can I let the Glossary (Formelverzeichnis) look like a table header with a line above and below the word "Formelverzeichnis"? merci in advance A

Comment: @aerioeus That might be better asked as a follow-up question (e.g. "How to change the glossary section header style?") Basically, the header is added using `\glossarysection[\glossarytoctitle]{\glossarytitle}` where `\glossarysection` by default either uses `\section*` or `\chapter*`. (In this example, it uses `\chapter*`.) So it's either a case of changing the style of unnumbered chapters or redefining `\glossarysection` to use a custom format.

Comment: O.k., then I will start a follow up question - merci again. 