# Issues with glossaries

Tags: glossaries

The problem is that my glossary appears in blank. The compiler doesn't tell me about errors. I have lots of packages, maybe some of them are conflicting? Below I'm showing how I'm implemeting the glossary.

```
%% document class
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumerate} % needed for some options in enumerate
\usepackage{makeidx} % needed for creating an index
\makeindex 
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1.8cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry} % needed for page border settings
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto,colorlinks=true,citecolor=black,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage[acronym,nopostdot,nogroupskip,style=super,nonumberlist,automake,toc]{glossaries} %Load glossaries package
\makeglossaries
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\makeatletter
\usepackage[intoc, spanish]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\xapptocmd{\appendices}{%
  \def\Hy@chapapp{appendixchapters}%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\newglossaryentry{Dc}{name={DC},description={Direct Current}}
\newglossaryentry{Pmdc}{name={PMDC},description={Permanent Magnet Direct Current}}
\newglossaryentry{Igbt}{name={IGBT},description={Insulated Gate Bipolar Transistor}}
\newglossaryentry{Pwm}{name={PWM},description={Pulse-Width Modulation}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\printnomenclature
\printglossary[title={Lista de Abreviaturas}] 
\chapter {Example}
This a glossary example \gls{Dc}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you run the `makeglossaries` script after the compilation?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm using Texmaker. I don't have much experience using it. How do I do that?

Comment: I think there are instructions on how to use `makeglossaries` with TeXMaker on TeX.SE. I don't use such editors.

Comment: Are the instructions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61099/using-texmaker-with-glossaries-on-windows) helpful?. Anyway, after compiling, `makeglossaries` and compiling again, I see your `DC` glossary entry in the glossary

Comment: There should be in some menu the Index option (see Tools or something else)

Comment: Still can't manage to show the glossary. I don't see anything related with `makeglossaries` in the texmaker software itself

Comment: @XavierPachecoPaulino: There is no auto-setup of course. You have to follow the instructions in the link I gave you or search on the site here with `TeXMaker glossaries` etc.

Comment: It works now. I had to install ActivePerl.