# How do I refer to the glossary section using ref?

Tags: glossaries

I am using the `glossaries` package. In the document, I would like to say "Please, refer to section \ref{my-glossary}". How can I do that?

Here's an example.

In the file `notes.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[section,numberedsection=autolabel]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{vae}{VAE}{variational auto-encoder}

\begin{document}

%\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{Abstract}
\acrshort{vae}.

Please, refer to section \ref{my-glossar}. 

\clearpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]\label{my-glossar}

\bibliography{biblio}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you added a `\label{my-glossar}` after the corresponding section/chapter?

Comment: Try to add ist right after the ` \printglossary` command.

Comment: See answer (untested, no MWE from your side).

Comment: You will probably have to add an "anchor", and even then, since a glossary is usually a starred section, you might consider using `\nameref` and rephrase as "see the section `\nameref{...}`".  (Or something similar with `\pageref`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by trial and error: reading the manual and looking at [Using Texmaker with glossaries on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61099).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[
    toc,
    section,
    numberedsection = autolabel,
    automake,
    ]{glossaries}
\glstoctrue

\makeglossaries %makeglossaries %

\newacronym{vae}{VAE}{variational auto-encoder}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Abstract}
\acrshort{vae}. 

Please, refer to section \ref{main}. 

\printglossary[type=main]

\end{document}
```

[image]