# How do I refer to the first page of the glossary?

Tags: cross-referencing, page-numbering, glossaries, pageref

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492748/how-do-i-refer-to-the-glossary-section-using-ref) is about making the glossary numbered, and referring to it by that number.

I'm instead asking about referring to the page where the ***unnumbered*** glossary starts. Since I'm using `\printglossaries` to print it, there's no label I can refer to in a `\pageref` command.

I'm assuming the solution should work for [such a simple example document](https://www.overleaf.com/project/639c4366c49363479d34cfd6).

Comment: Please share the link with your example.

Comment: @SimonDispa, doesn't the one at the end of the question work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code using `hyperref`'s `\autopageref`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[
toc,
section,
numberedsection = autolabel,
automake,
]{glossaries}
\glstoctrue

\makeglossaries %makeglossaries %

\newacronym{vae}{VAE}{variational auto-encoder}
\makeglossaries
    
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \section{Abstract}
    \acrshort{vae}. 
    
    Please, refer to section \ref{main}.
    
    Please, refer to \autopageref{main}. 
    
    \newpage \setcounter{page}{5}
    
    \printglossary[type=main]
    
\end{document}
```

For an unnumbered glossary

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[
toc,
section,
]{glossaries}
\glstoctrue
    
\renewcommand*{\glossarypreamble}{%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49780/161015
    \label{\currentglossary}%
}

\newacronym{vae}{VAE}{variational auto-encoder}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \section{Abstract}
    \acrshort{vae}. 
        
    The glossary starts on page~\pageref{main}.
    
    \newpage \setcounter{page}{5}
    
    \printglossary
\end{document}
```

OR

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[
toc,
section,
]{glossaries}
\glstoctrue

\newacronym{vae}{VAE}{variational auto-encoder}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \section{Abstract}
    \acrshort{vae}. 
        
    The glossary starts on page~\pageref{main}.
    
    \newpage \setcounter{page}{5}
    
    \printglossary[title={List of Acronyms\label{main}}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought that the assumption that the glossary stays unnumbered was obvious for contrast with the other question I linked. I've clarifiled.

Comment: @Enlico Please see the updated answer.